# How to select all records from one table that do not exist in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> table1 (id, name)
>   table2 (id, name)

Query:

```
SELECT name   
FROM table2  
-- that are not in table1 already
```

Comment: Look at the solution with UNION at the bottom which is orders of magnitude faster than any other solution listed here.

Answer (score 1271, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

**Q**: What is happening here?

**A**: Conceptually, we select all rows from `table1` and for each row we attempt to find a row in `table2` with the same value for the `name` column. If there is no such row, we just leave the `table2` portion of our result empty for that row. Then we constrain our selection by picking only those rows in the result where the matching row does not exist. Finally, We ignore all fields from our result except for the `name` column (the one we are sure that exists, from `table1`).

While it may not be the most performant method possible in all cases, it should work in basically every database engine ever that attempts to implement [ANSI 92 SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92)

Comment: @z-boss: It's also the least performant on SQL Server: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: @Kris let me clear a thing that you apply left join and table1 is left table ok but you apply condition on right table that is table 2 but i read that if you apply left join then you should apply where condition also on  left table other wise it will work as a inner join, would please explain me ?

Comment: @BunkerBoy: A left join allows rows on the right to not exist without that affecting the inclusion of rows on the left. An inner join requires rows on the left and the right to be present. What i'm doing here is applying some logic to basically get the reverse selection of an inner join.

Comment: Has anyone actually tested this SQL statement?

Comment: Seems super slow on my dataset. 150k varchars

Comment: omg this helped visualize very easily, others had put it like 5 different ways but this helped. simple: first you get left join, everything in A, and everything in B that matches A. But as happens in left join fields which don't join are just null. Then you tell, ok i only want that are null. This way you now have all rows in A that didn't have a match In B

Comment: It should be noted that this solutions (accepted and voted up) is the only one, I think, the could be edited for a scenario where more than one field comes into play.  Specifically, I am returning field, field 2, field 3 from table one where the combination of field ad field2 is not in the second table.  Other than modifying the join in this answer, I do not see a way to do it with some of the other "more efficient answers" argued for below

Comment: I do understand that we are selecting those rows from the resultant table where the name is NULL, but why address the table as t2, when its the resultant table of join?

Comment: @SudipM: I don't undferstand your question but the alias "t2" is just that; an alias for the example. It carries no meaning whatsoever.

Comment: @Kris: Nono, I am not talking about t2 as why the alis name is like that, I feel t2.name is never NULL, but its some of entries of name column of resultant table after join becomes NULL, so why address that resultant table by t2?

Comment: t2.Name will be null in the join (as will all the fields in t2) if there's no row that matches the join condition (It is a LEFT JOIN afterall) this is also why we need it in the WHERE clause, because if we'd try to do the filtering in the join here, the entire result row will not be selected at all. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Just make sure you use "WHERE t2.name IS NULL" and not "AND t2.name IS NULL" because "and" will not give correct results. I don't really understand why but it's a fact, I tested it.

Comment: @user890332: AND (in the join clause) will check in the actual table whereas the WHERE construction checks in the selection result. Since the table doesn't actually contain the NULL, the row will not be in the selection result to be processed at all. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I understand, but the strange thing is when I use "and" it returned all the records in table A. According to what you wrote, shouldn't it return no results?

Comment: @AgustíSánchez Tested it just now, in SQLite. Query seems to work!

Comment: I think you got table 1 and 2 swapped with respect to the original question. But I got it working for my use case (one N:N table with both foreign keys to a master table, and I'm looking for FK constraint violations. SQLite performance is sub 100ms for tables sized 125k and 700k respectively)

Answer (score 352):

You can either do

```
SELECT name
FROM table2
WHERE name NOT IN
    (SELECT name 
     FROM table1)
```

or

```
SELECT name 
FROM table2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM table1 
     WHERE table1.name = table2.name)
```

---

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null) for 3 techniques to accomplish this

Comment: This is incredibly slow with large amounts of data.

Comment: Yeah, indeed it is very slow

Comment: Shouldn't it be "from table1" in the subquery of the not exists query.

Comment: Very confused at how this got so many upvotes. I find it very hard to think of a reason to ever use this, when there is an approach to this problem that is incredibly faster with roughly the same number of keystrokes.

Comment: @searchengine27 Is it really that slow when we have query optimizers?

Answer (score 173):

I don't have enough rep points to vote up [froadie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686280/7724384). But I have to disagree with the comments on [Kris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686266/7724384). The following answer:

```
SELECT name
FROM table2
WHERE name NOT IN
    (SELECT name 
     FROM table1)
```

Is FAR more efficient in practice. I don't know why, but I'm running it against 800k+ records and the difference is tremendous with the advantage given to the 2nd answer posted above. Just my $0.02.

Comment: In the NOT IN query the subquery is performed only once, in the EXISTS query the subquery is performed for every row

Comment: you are awesome :) this way I convert my 25 sec query using left join to just 0.1 sec

Comment: answers are not in any specific order, so *second answer* does not mean what you thought it meant.

Comment: I think this also may be the only solution if you're looking to add some extra filters/criteria to the sub query.

Comment: 2023 And still the best answer for me, because if use this query it take just 0.1 sec.

Comment: This indeed is an amazing option. Worked like a charm for me where Table 1 had 5.7 million matching entries & table 2 had about 3 million entries, on SAP HANA database.

Answer (score 99):

```
SELECT <column_list>
FROM TABLEA a
LEFTJOIN TABLEB b 
ON a.Key = b.Key 
WHERE b.Key IS NULL;
```

[image]

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql/

Comment: [Say NO to Venn Diagrams When Explaining JOINs](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/)

Comment: Too bad Join diagrams are much less clear and much harder to understand intuitively than Venn diagrams.

Comment: Thank you for the diagrams

Answer (score 53):

This is pure set theory which you can achieve with the `minus` operation.

```
select id, name from table1
minus
select id, name from table2
```

Comment: Do you think this is much efficient than left join ?

Comment: It should be. The minus command is designed for this exact situation. Of course the only way to judge for any particular data set is to try it both ways and see which runs faster.

Comment: In T-SQL, the set operator is "except". This is very convenient for me and has not caused any slowdown.

Comment: In SQLite, the "minus" operator is also "except".

Comment: MySQL do not support MINUS operator.

Comment: Now you are talking, thanks. As Izzy mentioned above, you can also use EXCEPT

Comment: Note almost all databases apart from Oracle use the ANSI standard term `EXCEPT` instead of `MINUS`. I think more recent versions of Oracle also support EXCEPT.

Comment: Not enough people understand how to use SQL set operators like EXCEPT and INTERSECT, they are very under-utilized.

Answer (score 21):

Here's what worked best for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM @T1
EXCEPT
SELECT a.*
FROM @T1 a
JOIN @T2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

This was more than twice as fast as any other method I tried.

Comment: Thanks, This work well with large amount of Data too! But I'm just wondering about the 'Except' term.

Comment: 767ms for me on 5k records across 200k records. Everything else took minutes.

Comment: regarding the EXCEPT in T-SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax

Answer (score 18):

Watch out for pitfalls. If the field `Name` in `Table1` contain Nulls you are in for surprises.
Better is:

```
SELECT name
FROM table2
WHERE name NOT IN
    (SELECT ISNULL(name ,'')
     FROM table1)
```

Comment: COALESCE > ISNULL (ISNULL is a useless T-SQL addition to the language that does nothing new or better than COALESCE)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `EXCEPT` in mssql or `MINUS` in oracle, they are identical according to :

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/07/sql-server-except-clause-in-sql-server-is-similar-to-minus-clause-in-oracle/

Answer (score 8):

That work sharp for me

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[table1] t1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[table2] t2 ON t1.[t1_ID] = t2.[t2_ID]
WHERE t2.[t2_ID] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

All the above queries are incredibly slow on big tables. A change of strategy is needed. Here there is the code I used for a DB of mine, you can transliterate changing the fields and table names.

This is the strategy: you create two implicit temporary tables and make a union of them.

1. The first temporary table comes from a selection of all the rows of the first original table the fields of which you wanna control that are NOT present in the second original table.
2. The second implicit temporary table contains all the rows of the two original tables that have a match on identical values of the column/field you wanna control.
3. The result of the union is a table that has more than one row with the same control field value in case there is a match for that value on the two original tables (one coming from the first select, the second coming from the second select) and just one row with the control column value in case of the value of the first original table not matching any value of the second original table.
4. You group and count. When the count is 1 there is not match and, finally, you select just the rows with the count equal to 1.

Seems not elegant, but it is orders of magnitude faster than all the above solutions.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** enable the INDEX on the columns to be checked.

```
SELECT name, source, id
FROM 
(
    SELECT name, "active_ingredients" as source, active_ingredients.id as id 
        FROM active_ingredients

    UNION ALL
        
    SELECT active_ingredients.name as name, "UNII_database" as source, temp_active_ingredients_aliases.id as id 
    FROM active_ingredients
    INNER JOIN temp_active_ingredients_aliases ON temp_active_ingredients_aliases.alias_name = active_ingredients.name

) tbl
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use following query structure :

`SELECT t1.name FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.fk_id != t1.id;`

table1 :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Amit |
| 2 | Sagar |

table2 :

| id | fk_id | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | amit@ma.com |

Output:

| name |
| --- |
| Sagar |

Answer (score 4):

First define alias of table like `t1` and `t2`.
After that get record of second table.
After that match that record using `where` condition:

```
SELECT name FROM table2 as t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 WHERE t1.name = t2.name)
```

Comment: Yours is the same [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686280/13664939) answer. Please read all the answers especially before answering old questions.

Comment: the professional of the others answers replication!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to repost (since I'm not cool enough yet to comment) in the correct answer....in case anyone else thought it needed better explaining.

```
SELECT temp_table_1.name
FROM original_table_1 temp_table_1
LEFT JOIN original_table_2 temp_table_2 ON temp_table_2.name = temp_table_1.name
WHERE temp_table_2.name IS NULL
```

And I've seen syntax in FROM needing commas between table names in mySQL but in sqlLite it seemed to prefer the space.

The bottom line is when you use bad variable names it leaves questions.  My variables should make more sense.  And someone should explain why we need a comma or no comma.

Answer (score 3):

See query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE
id NOT IN (SELECT 
        e.id
    FROM
        Table1 e
            INNER JOIN
        Table2 s ON e.id = s.id);
```

Conceptually would be: Fetching the matching records in subquery and then in main query fetching the records which are not in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions above but they did not work in my case. The following query worked for me.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   table_1
WHERE  NAME NOT IN
       (SELECT    a.NAME
        FROM      table_1 AS a
        LEFT JOIN table_2 AS b
        ON        a.NAME = b.NAME
        WHERE     any further condition);
```