# Ambiguous left joins in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, jet

I want to convert the following query from T-SQL

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    A                            LEFT JOIN
    B ON A.field1 = B.field1     LEFT JOIN
    C ON C.field1 = A.field2 AND
         C.field2 = B.field2
```

to Jet SQL. 
Now MS Access does not accept ambiguous queries.  How can I do that?  I can't put the second comparison in the `WHERE` clause.  Why?  Because my scenario is that I am selecting records that does not exist in C.

[How to select all records from one table that do not exist in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table)

Now, how do you that in MS Access?  Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a derived table to make this work in MS Access:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT A.Field1, A.Field2 As A2, B.Field2 
   FROM A 
   LEFT JOIN B ON A.field1 = B.field1) AS x 
LEFT JOIN C ON  x.A2 = C.field1 AND  x.field2= C.field2
```

Comment: Ouch!  It's so painful querying in MS Access!  Chosen as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

From Help [LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN Operations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/left-join-right-join-operations-HP001032251.aspx)

> You can link multiple ON clauses. See the discussion of clause linking
>   in the INNER JOIN topic to see how this is done.
>
> You can also link several ON clauses in a JOIN statement, using the
>   following syntax:

```
SELECT fields 
FROM table1 
     INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 compopr table2.field1 
                          AND ON table1.field2 compopr table2.field2)
                          OR ON table1.field3 compopr table2.field3)];
```

But works this (it seems there is an error in help):

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
     LEFT JOIN B ON A.field1 = B.field1
     LEFT JOIN C ON (C.field1 = A.field2 AND C.field2 = B.field2)
```

Comment: Mine returns an error Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ".

Comment: Hi Igor, I would like to clarify if you've tested the script.  Shouldn't there be a parenthesis with Tables B and C or A and B?

Comment: @yoitsfrancis Yes, I've tested the script and parentheses are essential as in my last updated script.

Comment: Hi Igor, it returns a JOIN expression not supported in my end