# ActiveRecord - get results ONLY if not in other table

Tags: sql, activerecord, codeigniter-2, pyrocms

There is a stackoverflow question that solves my sql query, but I cant seem to do this is CodeIgnighter.

so far I came up with

```
$this->db->select('shop_coupons_assoc.*');
$this->db->select('shop_products.*');
$this->db->where('shop_products.id IS NULL');
$this->db->join('shop_coupons_assoc', 'shop_coupons_assoc.product_id = shop_products.id', 'left');
```

article on SO that seems to be the SQL im trying to do

**update**
My Question: How would I write the SQL in Codeignighter(active record format)

-the above code does not seem to execute

Examples of what i need. Just cant find the documentation for codeignighter

[SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

[How to select all records from one table that do not exist in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table)

Comment: So what's the question again? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put this below your script and use var_dump to test it:

```
$result = $this->db->get()->result();
var_dump(result);
```

**EDIT:**
I see the error now:

```
$this->db->where('shop_products.id IS NULL');
```

Should be

```
$this->db->where('shop_products.id IS', NULL);
```

You probably overlooked the comma and accolade after the fieldname in the documentation. Also the blank page is probably because your servers php.ini has error_reporting turned of or because you are working in a production environment.

Comment: Im just getting a black screen, I did a trace and its failing at this line  ''IS NULL''