# How to select all records from one table which are not already selected by user?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I know there exist a similar question [How to select all records from one table that do not exist in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table)  but i have a different scenario

I have a `TotalTrainings` that consist of all records

```
TraningCode |  TraningName
1                   A
2                   B
3                   C
4                   D
5                   E
```

and another table `SelectedTraining`

```
TraningCode |  TraningName | EmpCode | AppraisalID
1                   A           7190      12
2                   B           7190      12
3                   C           8132      10
4                   D           5555      08
5                   E           8132      10
```

Now i had to retrieve all records(trainings) from `TotalTrainings` which are not selected by `EmpCode = 7190` having `appraisalId 12`

Note alias of `TotalTraining` is `tt` and `SelectedTraining` is `st`

I have done written query like this :

```
select tt.trainingCode from TotalTraining tt left join SelectedTraining st
on tt.trainingCode = st.trainingCode where st.trainingCode is null 
and EmpCode=7190 and appraisalId =12
```

but it is giving no result .

I have achieved the same with `NOT IN` and it is perfectly working

```
select tt.trainingCode from TotalTraining tt where tt.trainingCode not in 
(
select st.trainingCode from SelectedTraining st where 
EmpCode=7190 and appraisalId =12
)
```

I want to achieve with `Joins` , Can anyone tell me where i might be wrong.

**Note** : Kindly Ignore Typos here such as case sensitive `AppraisalId` and `appraisalId` because that is not the problem

**Expected output is**

```
3
4
5
```

because these training till now not have been selected by `EmpCode 7190`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first query, you need to push most of the conditions to the `on` clause -- all the conditions on the second table:

```
select tt.trainingCode
from TotalTraining tt left join
     SelectedTraining st
     on tt.trainingCode = st.trainingCode and
        st.EmpCode = 7190 and
        st.appraisalId = 12
where st.trainingCode is null ;
```