# How to select rows without appropriate keys?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here are 2 tables:

```
declare @Table1 table (ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Value int)
declare @Table2 table (ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Value int)

insert into @Table1 (ID, Value)
select 1, 100
union all
select 2, 101
union all
select 3, 103
union all
select 4, 104
union all
select 5, 105

insert into @Table2 (ID, Value)
select 1, 100
union all
select 2, 110
union all
select 3, 111
```

I need to select all rows from first table, which Value's values are not in Table2. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Select * from Table1 where value not in(select distinct value from table2)
```

Comment: What if some value in second table is NULL?

Comment: It's not new question, because the upper query doesn't work if Value's value is NULL.

Comment: This post might help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t1.*
FROM @Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t2.value = t1.value
WHERE t2.value IS NULL