# Restore woocommerce orders

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

Recently my server team replaced my database and they put our previous Database .  So we lost our order details of one day[particular day] .  Now the server team give the backup that contain the lost day order details .

Now please tell how can i restore these orders ?

I cannot replace our database with the given backup , because today also we have orders .

Could anyone tell the step by step instruction ?

I Created a new database and uploaded backup .I understand that order are saved in wp_posts, and post meta .

So what i need to do ? , i export the all the order in that date from wp_posts,and post meta as sql file . Then just need to import it in to current database ? It make any problem ?

Comment: If you are not confident with WP and MySQL and you don't want to mess your database, I suggest you to look for a dev doing that for you.

Comment: I am confident friend . But i need to make sure and get suggestion from others . Friend do you phase the same issue ? please share your idea .

Comment: You can select all rows from backup table that are not present into your main table and then insert those. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table

Comment: Really thank you friend . But do you do this operation in WordPress database before ?

Comment: And before any operation save a new backup of the database. No, I haven't ever restored a wp table content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This case is quite complicated, because as you can guess  you have certainly in both databases (in your backup and actual databases) the same orders ID for different orders.
When an order is made it populate the database tables "post", "postmeta" (and  maybe some extra tables related to woocommerce that some wooCommerce plugins have created).

**RETRIEVING THE MISSING DATA :** 
First in "post" **backup** table you have to find all "post_id" with a **shop_order** "post_type", starting at a specific date : 
`SELECT *  FROM 'posts' WHERE 'post_date' > '2016-03-15 00:00:00' AND 'post_type' LIKE 'shop_order' ORDER BY 'post_id' ASC` 
*(you have to set the correct beginning date and hour in here)*

With all those **post_id** you are going to retrieve all the related data in "postmeta" table: 
`SELECT * FROM 'postmeta' WHERE 'post_id' > 2059 ORDER BY 'meta_id' ASC` 
*(you have to replace **post_id** "2059" by your corresponding real one… )*

**PREPARING NEW DATA TO INSERT :** 
For "posts" table, you will have to shift all the different ID numbers for "post_id", before inserting them in your actual database, with new non existing yet values depending on the IDs already used by your actual database.

For "postmeta" table, you will have to replace all old "post_id" with the new values just generated in your "posts" table.

**You will have to put your shop in maintenance mode to avoid new orders (for example with this free [Maintenance Mode](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/lj-maintenance-mode/) plugin)**

You have to be used to MySQL and i think it's better to test all in a duplicated version of your webshop. **Make backups before…**

> **EDIT**
>   Your website and your database are quiet heavy as you say in this [wordpress.stackexchange post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221781/restore-woocommerce-orders) 10 Gb for your website and 2 Gb for the database.
>   **THE QUICKEST AND EASY WAY**:
>   So may be the best option is to **create a new database** on the same server **importing the backup with the missed orders**. Once done you can do the steps below
>   1) Put your webshop in maintenance mode *(for example with this free [Maintenance Mode](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/lj-maintenance-mode/) plugin)*.
>   2) Make a backup of your database (just in case).
>   3) in your wp-config.php file change the database (to the old one with missed orders).
>   4) Immediately activate and Enable **Maintenance Mode** plugin. 
>   5) Install [WooCommerce Simply Order Export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-simply-order-export/) plugin and enable it.
>   6) Export your one day missing orders data as CSV or XML file.
>   7) in your wp-config.php file change the database (to the actual one with all new orders).
>   8) Enable **WooCommerce Simply Order Export** and import the CSV (or XML) file. 
>   8) Disable **WooCommerce Simply Order Export** and  **Maintenance Mode** plugins (and delete them if you want).
>   
>   You are done!
>   *Thanks to **Mehul Gohil** [in that post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221781/restore-woocommerce-orders)*

Regards

Comment: Sorry friend for very late response . The answer you are given is the best one .Mehul Gohil answer is also the same way .  thank you  @Mehul Gohil

Comment: How can I import the CSV with the WooCommerce Simply Order Export? This plugin can only export orders... not importing?!