# Woocommerce Export/Import Staging Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, staging

Hi I am on the latest version of woocommerce and everything is up to date.  I am using a staging environment to be able to make changes to my e-commerce site and test them before making them live.  However, while I am in staging my live site continues to get orders and unfortunately orders are posted to the posts and postmeta tables which are the same DB tables for pages where I am making the changes.

Therefore, what I am trying to do is export out the orders using the wordpress export orders, then move the staging site to live and then use the wordpress tools importer and re-import the orders.  This process seems to be correct, however when I import the order the order #, customer, address, email and everything seems to be imported correctly except what product the customer actually ordered.  Here is a screenshot of the table showing empty "Purchased" column.  [image]

I have looked into other plugins to handle this via csv but I feel this can be accomplished without those? I have also tried exporting and importing "all content" assuming that maybe those are done in another wp_ table but that did not work as well.  Is anyone else facing this problem or is there something else I should try or a different import/export plugin? I have tried doing different import settings by assigning the import content to different users and that didn't work either.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Have a look to that thread: [Restore woocommerce orders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234875/restore-woocommerce-orders/).

Comment: You can easily export and import WooCommerce Orders with line item details with this WordPress Free Plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-import-export-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily export and import WooCommerce Orders with line item details with this [WordPress Free Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-import-export-for-woocommerce/)