# Get all records in Table B that don't exist in Table A

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Got this question from a job interview via skype. I managed to take a screenshot of the question.

[image]
I imagine it's the reverse of a RIGHT JOIN, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: A right join is just a left join written back to front

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2686254/3404097

Comment: Hi. Read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way of doing this via an anti-join:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM departments d
LEFT JOIN students s
    ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = s.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE
    s.DEPARTMENT_ID IS NULL;
```

We can also use an `EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM departments d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM students s WHERE s.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID);
```

Comment: Congratulations. You're hired.

Comment: @Strawberry I can't get a good job.  The coding challenges always defeat me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a using a subquery. Here are two example of MySQL query. You can try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DEPARTMENT 
WHERE 
DEPERTMENT_ID NOT IN (
   SELECT DEPERTMENT_ID 
   FROM STUDENTS 
   GROUP BY DEPERTMENT_ID)
```

**Another way using where not exists:**

```
   SELECT d.*
    FROM departments d
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM students s WHERE s.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM department_table D
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
            FROM student_table B
            WHERE A.department_id=B.department_id);
```