# LEFT JOIN THREE tables

Tags: sql, oracle

How to create sql query to select the distinct table A data
as in the image [image]

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: It won't necessarily be a left join.

Answer (score 6):

One method is `minus`:

```
select . . .
from a
minus
select . . .
from b
minus
select . . .
from c;
```

Or, `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where . . . ) and
      not exists (select 1 from c where . . . );
```

You don't clarify what the matching conditions are, so I've used `. . .` for generality.

These two versions *are not the same*.  The first returns unique combinations of columns from `a` where those same columns are not in `b` or `c`.  The second returns *all* columns from `a`, where another set is not in `b` or `c`.

Comment: Ah, yes. If only Oracle had `EXCEPT ALL`, or `MINUS ALL`, like DB2 and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 6):

If you *must* use `LEFT JOIN` to implement what is really an [anti join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_(%E2%96%B7)), then do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.a_id
LEFT JOIN c ON c.a_id = a.a_id
WHERE b.a_id IS NULL
AND c.a_id IS NULL
```

This reads:

- `FROM`: Get all rows from a
- `LEFT JOIN`: Optionally get the matching rows from b and c as well
- `WHERE`: In fact, no. Keep only those rows from a, for which there was no match in b and c

Using `NOT EXISTS()` is a more elegant way to run an anti-join, though. I tend to not recommend `NOT IN()` because of the delicate implications around three valued logic - which can lead to not getting any results *at all*.

#### Side note on using Venn diagrams for joins

A lot of people like using Venn diagrams to illustrate joins. I think this is a bad habit, Venn diagrams model *set operations* (like `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, or in your case `EXCEPT` / `MINUS`) very well. [Joins are filtered cross products, which is an entirely different kind of operation. I've blogged about it here](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/).

Answer (score 1):

Select what isn't in B nor C nor in A inner join B inner join C

```
Select * from A
where A.id not in ( select coalesce(b.id,c.id) AS ID
                    from b full outer join c on (b.id=c.id) )
```

or also: --- you don't need a join so jou can avoid doing it

```
select * from A
where a.id not in (select coalesce (B.ID,C.ID) AS ID from B,C)
```

Comment: No, in a join, at least b.id or c.id exists so i'm sure at least one value exixts (I assume ID field is not null)

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

Someone already ask something related to your question, you should see it
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table)