# Fastest way of merging two tables on distinct rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with the same column name: `CookieID (bigint)`

1. table (Cookies) has 5 million records
2. table (CookiePurpose) has 10 million records

I want to create a new table, with only the CookieIDs from #1 that do not exist in #2.

The following approach took over 20 minutes.

```
CREATE TABLE #KnownCookieIDs

(
    [CookieID] [bigint] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO 
#KnownCookieIDs
SELECT CookieID FROM CookiePurpose
EXCEPT
SELECT CookieID from Cookies
```

Is there a faster way to achieve this?

**Update**

I was testing on an Azure database with a S0 tier plan, which has 10 DTUs. Figured the long query time was because of this, so I am in the process of exporting the DB to my local machine, and will try out your suggestions from there.

Comment: What indexes do the tables have?

Comment: There is no index on the CookieID column on theCookiePurpose table. Will add that and test with the suggestions below.

Answer (score 1):

This query should work faster:

```
CREATE TABLE #KnownCookieIDs

(
    [CookieID] [bigint] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO 
    #KnownCookieIDs
SELECT 
    c.CookieID 
FROM 
    Cookie c
    LEFT JOIN CookiePurpose cp ON c.CookieID = cp.CookieID
WHERE
    cp.CookieID IS NULL
```

Comment: I think your tables are backwards

Comment: Except for using the wrong table as @UnhandledExcepSean said, this should be faster, especially if you have an index on CookieID on both tables. OTOH, you're already getting 500,000 records/minute. It's possible that you have reached a system performance limit (CPU/dIsk, etc.). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table

Comment: I said nothing in regards to the performance. The  issue I see in your SQL is that, they want all Cookie records missing a corresponding CookiePurpose record, yours does the opposite.

Comment: LEFT JOIN is apparently still much faster than EXCEPT: https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-commands-performance-comparison-not-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-vs-except/

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Thank you. The query of the owner of the question specifies a different sequence than in the text. I changed the tables as described in the description.

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to do tad of experimentation. The result on a data set 1/10th the size of the OP's showed a sub-select performed better than a left join. Although, I would expect the left join to work the best in larger data sets. UPDATE: I set up a dataset like the OP and the LEFT JOIN still didn't out perform the sub-select, but it was very close.

Ensuring there are indexes on the two tables is critical for speed. So make sure your tables are indexed appropriately.

```
/*
DROP TABLE Cookie
CREATE TABLE Cookie ([CookieID] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,Dummy bit)

DROP TABLE CookiePurpose
CREATE TABLE CookiePurpose (CookiePurposeID [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, [CookieID] [bigint] NOT NULL)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_CookiePurpose_CookieID ON dbo.CookiePurpose (CookieID)

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @CookieCounter BIGINT=(SELECT COUNT(CookieID) FROM Cookie)
WHILE @CookieCounter<500000 BEGIN INSERT INTO Cookie(Dummy) SELECT 1; SET @CookieCounter=@CookieCounter+1; END

DECLARE @CookiePurposeCounter BIGINT=(SELECT COUNT(CookieID) FROM CookiePurpose)
WHILE @CookiePurposeCounter<1000000 BEGIN INSERT INTO CookiePurpose(CookieID) SELECT Round(( ( 1000000000 - 1 - 1 ) * Rand() + 1 ), 0); SET @CookiePurposeCounter=@CookiePurposeCounter+1; END

*/

--EXCEPT: 300ms @ 1/10 data; 2917ms for full data
DECLARE @start DATETIME2,@end DATETIME2; SET @start=GETDATE()
DECLARE  @KnownCookieIDs TABLE ([CookieID] [bigint] NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @KnownCookieIDs
    SELECT CookieID FROM CookiePurpose
    EXCEPT
    SELECT CookieID from Cookie
SET @end=GETDATE(); SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@start,@end) AS [ms elapsed];
GO

--LEFT JOIN: 123ms @ 1/10 data; 1093ms for full data
DECLARE @start DATETIME2,@end DATETIME2; SET @start=GETDATE()
DECLARE  @KnownCookieIDs TABLE ([CookieID] [bigint] NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @KnownCookieIDs
    SELECT c.CookieID
    FROM Cookie c
    LEFT JOIN  CookiePurpose cp ON cp.CookieID=c.CookieID
    WHERE cp.CookieID IS NULL
SET @end=GETDATE(); SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@start,@end) AS [ms elapsed];
GO

--sub-select: 113 ms @ 1/10 data; 1046ms for full data
DECLARE @start DATETIME2,@end DATETIME2; SET @start=GETDATE()
DECLARE  @KnownCookieIDs TABLE ([CookieID] [bigint] NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @KnownCookieIDs
    SELECT c.CookieID
    FROM Cookie c
    WHERe c.CookieID NOT IN (
        SELECT CookieID FROM CookiePurpose
    )
SET @end=GETDATE(); SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@start,@end) AS [ms elapsed];
GO


--Delete: 767ms @ 1/10 data; 8450ms for full data
DECLARE @start DATETIME2,@end DATETIME2; SET @start=GETDATE()
DECLARE  @KnownCookieIDs TABLE ([CookieID] [bigint] NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @KnownCookieIDs
    SELECT c.CookieID
    FROM Cookie c

DELETE c
FROM @KnownCookieIDs c
INNER JOIN CookiePurpose cp ON cp.CookieID=c.CookieID

SET @end=GETDATE(); SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@start,@end) AS [ms elapsed];
GO
```