# How to select rows from table1 which are not in table2 according to FieldX in table2 - but relevant for each different value of Field2 in table 2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is for MS SQL Server 2016.

I have `Table1` which contains an ID and a Name column (of layouts to populate a html dropdown box).

This dropdown (stores its ID value into `Field1` of `table2`) should only list items which are not already used in rows in `field1` of `Table2`.

The query for this alone would be solved with this SO answer here: [How to select all records from one table that do not exist in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table))

But I have 1 additional requirement:

Within `Table2`, I have a 2nd column (holds the `ClubID` - it is also represented by a dropdown, populated from a 3rd table with ID and name) which allows the user to select a club. Now the query which populates `Field1` in `Table2` should only show items from `Table1` which do not yet exist for the chosen `Club` within `Table2` (`Field2` will be defined first by the user in order to show the correct items in `Field1`).

How to do this? (I am unfortunately no SQL Server expert and this is a bit too high for me).

I already have tried the following query and some variants of it to solve it but this didn't work:

```
SELECT 
    t1.TacMasterLayoutId, t1.TacMasterLayoutName.Name
FROM 
    Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 t2 ON t2.TacMasterLayoutId = t1.TacMasterLayoutId
WHERE 
    t2.TacMasterLayoutId IS NULL 
    AND T2.ChainAndSingleRessortId = <FilterId>
```

(`FilterId` contains the ID of the selected club).

As requested, some sample data:

Table1: (Layouts)

```
ID          Name
 1          CoverLetter
 2          AccountingReceipt
 3          IdlePeriodConfirmation
 4          Contract
 5          BonusPeriodConfirmation
```

Table3: (Clubs)

```
ID          Name
 1          Club1
 2          Club2
```

Table2: (Club-Layouts - used to hold all layouts which have been assigned to the Clubs)

```
ID          Club-ID           Layout-ID
 1          1                 1
 2          2                 1
 3          1                 2
 4          2                 4
```

Desired output:

**Case 1:** When Selected Club-ID=1:

(These Layout-IDs are already used within Club-Layouts:)

```
ID          Club-ID           Layout-ID
 1                1           1
 3                1           2
```

Therefore I need the following output from the query:

```
ID         Name
 3          IdlePeriodConfirmation
 4          Contract
 5          BonusPeriodConfirmation
```

**Case 2:** When Selected Club-ID=2:

(These Layout-IDs are already used within Club-Layouts:)

```
ID          Club-ID           Layout-ID
 2          2                 1
 4          2                 4
```

Therefore I need the following output from the query:

```
ID         Name
 2          AccountingReceipt
 3          IdlePeriodConfirmation
 5          BonusPeriodConfirmation
```

Hope this clarifies the situation.

Comment: Can you add few rows of sample data and expected results to your question?

Comment: share sampe data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

do inner join between table2 and table3 and then do left join with this outcome with table 1

```
 with cte AS
(select t3.ID,t2.ClubID,t2.LayoutID
 from Table3 t3 
join Table2 t2 on t3.ID=t2.ClubID
where t2.ClubID=1 -- you can change this condition as you need
) select t1.id,t1.name from table1 t1
 left join cte on t1.ID=cte.LayoutID
 where cte.LayoutID is null
```

[Demo in Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0fbc1a98d24c0eb5ac289fff2dc67e3a)

```
id  name
3   IdlePeriodConfirmation
4   Contract
5   BonusPeriodConfirmation
```

Comment: Hi @Zaynul,
wow - works! I really appreciate your effort - and I learned something new: dbfiddle :-)

For this I give you +1.

I currently still prefer my own solution as it seems for me (of course) easier to read - also for non SQL experts. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
select c.id as clubid, c.name as clubname, l.id as layoutid, l.name as layoutname
from layouts l
cross join clubs c
left outer join clublayouts cl
   on cl.layoutid = l.id
   and cl.clubid = c.id
where cl.id is null
/* and if you want the list for a single club add... */ and c.id = <some club id>
```

Comment: I will try your solution also.

Comment: @MichaelHafner I solved your problem with demo you can check

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies.

In the meantime, I solved it like this:

```
SELECT t1.TacMasterLayoutId, t1.TacMasterLayoutName
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN (select * from Table2 where T2.ChainAndSingleRessortId = <FilterId>) t2 ON t2.TacMasterLayoutId = t1.TacMasterLayoutId
WHERE t2.TacMasterLayoutId IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.TacMasterLayoutName
```