# Rails 5: Query which excludes results if they're associated with a specific record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I've got two models: `Playlist` and `Item`. I want to build a query which returns all playlists except those which have an specific item.

These are the models:

```
class Playlist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :playlist
end
```

This is a query which doesn't work since there could be playlists which have the specified item, but also several more, and if they have other items, they are included (which is what I don't want):

`Playlist.left_outer_joins(:items).where.not(items: { uid: id })`

For the record, my DBMS is **PostgreSQL 9.6**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a setup to quickly test this, but I think you can use a Rails `ActiveRecord` subquery:

```
Playlist.where.not(id: Item.select(:pl_id).where(id: id_to_exclude))
```

Here, `pl_id` is the name of the attribute in `Item` corresponding to the playlist Id. I'm also assuming that `id` is the primary key in each of your tables. This might be a compact way for a result, but may not be the most efficient from a query perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this can be written in a better way but it should work:

```
join_sql = Arel.sql(
  "LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON " \
  "(items.playlist_id = playlists.uid " \
  "AND items.some_id = '#{item.some_id}')"
)

Playlist.where(owner: owner)
        .joins(join_sql)
        .where(items: { playlist_id: nil })
```

The concept is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686266