# SQL - SELECT rows NOT EXISTS in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select the rows not present in table `B`, based on table `A`.

Unlike table `B`, table `A` has "_00" at the end of the titleid, and the column is called `title` instead of `titleid`.

**Table A**:

```
id | titleid
---+----------
1  | TEST1_00
2  | TEST2_00
3  | TEST3_00
4  | TEST4_00
```

**Table B**:

```
id | title
---+-------
1  | TEST1
2  | TEST2
```

I currently have:

```
SELECT `t1.titleid`
FROM `tableb t1`
LEFT JOIN `tablea t2` ON `t2.title + '_00' = t1.titleid`
WHERE `t2.title` IS NULL
```

How can I select the values which are present in `A` but not in `B`?

---

**Desired output**

```
id | title
---+----------
3  | TEST3_00
4  | TEST4_00
```

Comment: You list table "A" first in the `FROM` and check for the match on table "B".

Comment: This is obviously an easily found duplicate. [ask] Eg you could have googled your title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select all records from one table that do not exist in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table)

Comment: @philipxy Not with the complexity of this question. Did you downvote the question aswell?

Comment: Given your comment you still don't seem to have researched much. This neither shows research effort nor is helpful. Your last line is a misstatement of your first line, and neither your first line nor the rest explains "based on". So--"unclear. (It's good you gave an example though.) See the downvote arrow mouseover text. PS Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. [ask] [mcve]

Comment: Your use of back quotes is strange. MySQL puts them around table & column names. Please give a [mcve]. PS Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Comment: What question are you actually trying to ask? That you more or less understand the ON you want for your fuzzy match & the LEFT JOIN you want for non-matching rows, but that you can't find your typo? If so your question does not say that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT t1.titleid
 FROM tablea t1
 LEFT JOIN tableb t2 ON t2.title + '_00' = t1.titleid
 WHERE t2.title IS NULL
```

You want to pull Data from `Table A` , do a `left join` on `Table B` and pull data `where TableB.Title is null`.

Your Query was trying to pull data `where TableA.Title is NULL`.

Comment: This is misusing backquotes that you copied from the question where they were being misused.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this like that

```
SELECT `t1.titleid`
FROM `tablea t1`

WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.title FROM `tableb t2` WHERE `t1.titleid = t2.title+ '_00'`)
```

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Please format your code reasonably. Read the edit help re code blocks. Also you have cut & pasted misuse of back quotes from the question. This is an example of why code questions need a [mcve] & without one should be downvoted & closed, not answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` `tableb` instead if `tablea`

```
SELECT `t1.titleid`
FROM `tablea t1`
LEFT JOIN `tableb t2` ON `t1.titleid = t2.title+ '_00'`
WHERE `t2.title` IS NULL
```

This will show which records in `tablea` don't have a match in `tableb` and are `null`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from A where SUBSTRING(A.title,0, 6) in (select B.title from B )
```

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Please format your code reasonably. Read the edit help re code blocks. PS You are making assumptions about matching that the question does not give. Unclear questions should be downvoted & closed, not answered.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.