# comparing table records and return the extra

Tags: sql

Table1 has 10001 records and table2 has 10000 records. How do I get the extra record in table1 ?

Comment: You need to provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.  What do *you* mean by "extra record"?

Comment: Something like `select * from table1 t1 where t1.id not in (select t2.id from table2 t2)` i.e. all records within `t1` which don't have correponding records in `t2`

Comment: Define "extra record".  All we know is that Table1 has 1 more record than Table2.  And exactly every record in Table1 meets the criteria of "being 1 record".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that both tables have some kind of 1-to-1 relationship.
In that case, try the following:

```
SELECT tab1.*
FROM   tab1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   tab2
                   WHERE  tab1.id = tab2.id);
```

Comment: Thank you Buddy. I believe this works for me. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, you can get all records from table1 that do not exists in table 2 this way:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

More info [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table)