# How i can show all classes that a student isn't stay in adonis?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have three tables:

### **students**

id INT 
name VARCHAR

### **class**

id INT 
description VARCHAR

### **student_classes**

id INT 
student_id (FOREIGN KEY of students.id) 
class_id (FOREIGN KEY of class.id)

How i can return all classes of a student that is not in student_classes?
I receive the `student_id` in `request.params.student_id`, i try something like:

```
async getAvailableClassesOfAStudent({ request }){
  const classes = await Database
    .query()
    .select('class.*')
    .from('class')
    .leftJoin('student_classes', 'class.id', 'student_classes.class_id')
    .whereNotIn('student_classes.student_id', request.params.student_id) 

  return classes 
}
```

I'm getting:

> select "class".* from "class" left join "student_classes" on
>   "class"."id" = "student_classes"."class_id" where
>   "student_classes"."student_id" not in $1 - syntax error at or near
>   "$1"

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help you : [How to select all records from one table that do not exist in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686254/how-to-select-all-records-from-one-table-that-do-not-exist-in-another-table)

Something like :

```js
...

const classes = await Database
    .query()
    .select('class.*')
    .from('class')
    .leftJoin('student_classes', 'class.id', 'student_classes.class_id')
    .whereNull('student_classes.student_id') 

...
```