# Filtering data using multiple AND operators in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, postgresql

I have a table named skills :

[image: screen shot for skills table]

I want to search for users having skill java with 2+ year experience and also having skill jquery with 1+ year experience.

I tried this :

```
SELECT `userid` FROM `skills`
WHERE `skill` =   'java' AND `experience` > 2
  AND `skill` = 'jquery' AND `experience` > 1
```

The expected result is 15. but the query returned an empty result set.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

#### Note:

The number of conditions in where clause may vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your `WHERE`-clause :

```
WHERE `skill` =   'java' AND `experience` > 2
  AND `skill` = 'jquery' AND `experience` > 1
```

What this means, is that you're selecting elements that must match EACH of the following conditions :

- `skill` = 'java'
- `experience` > 2
- `skill` = 'jquery'
- `experience` > 1

This will ALWAYS return the an empty result set, because the value of skill for a single record in the table can never be both equal to 'java' and equal to 'jquery'.

The best way to fix it, is to use a table join :

```
SELECT S1.userid
 FROM skills As S1
 INNER JOIN skills As S2
     ON S1.userid = S2.userid
 WHERE S1.skill =   'java' AND S1.experience > 2
   AND S2.skill = 'jquery' AND S2.experience > 1
```

If you want to search for additional skills, just add one join per skill you want to add :

```
SELECT S1.userid
 FROM skills As S1
 INNER JOIN skills As S2
     ON S1.userid = S2.userid
 INNER JOIN skills As S3
     ON S1.userid = S3.userid
 WHERE S1.skill =   'java' AND S1.experience > 2
   AND S2.skill = 'jquery' AND S2.experience > 1
   AND S3.skill =    'PHP' AND S3.experience > 1
```

Comment: What to do if i have more skills to search with? I think each time I have to add an inner join for each search criteria.

Comment: @MeeraMBabu : You can use as many joins as you want. Check the update at the bottom of my answer

Comment: please edit your answer for selecting distinct S1.userid.

Comment: @MeeraMBabu : What do you mean? All values returned by your query should already be distinct, assuming that every user can not have the same skill more than once.

Comment: If i have to search with 'OR' ie. For candidates having experience in java or jquery, userid is repeating.In that case,i think distinct must be used.  Am I right?

Comment: What to do if i have to search for user that dont have experience in a particular skill?

Comment: @MeeraMBabu : Assuming that you have a user table with a field named id, you should be able to do something like `SELECT id As UserId FROM users LEFT JOIN skills ON skills.userid = users.id WHERE skills.userid IS NULL`, to get all user ids of users without any skills in the skill table. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886095/whats-the-best-way-to-use-left-outer-join-to-check-for-non-existence-of-related

Comment: @JohnSlegars :I got that by joining with the user table.Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT userid
FROM skills 
WHERE (skill = 'java' AND experience > 2) 
      OR        
      (skill = 'jquery' AND experience > 1)
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill) = 2
```

The `WHERE` clause predicates return users having either of the skills (or both). The `HAVING` clause makes sure only users having both skills are returned.

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of 'HAVING COUNT'

Comment: @MeeraMBabu `HAVING` predicate is applied to the whole user group: so `COUNT(DISTINCT skill) = 2` essentially means get me users having *both* skills, i.e. 'java' **and** 'jquery'.

Comment: How to update the query if i have to search with more skills?

Comment: @MeeraMBabu You have to add additional predicates in the `WHERE` clause using `OR` operator and increment `2` number in `HAVING` clause accordingly.