# sql problem with WHERE ('field' <> value)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sql queries, one which retrieves all the Event records for a given topic id and another which is supposed to retrieve all Event records excluding given topic id, but doesn't.

The first query retrieves the correct records

```
SELECT `events`.* 
FROM `events` INNER JOIN events_topics ON events.id = events_topics.event_id
WHERE (events_topics.topic_id = 75)
```

The second query which is supposed to exclude events does not exclude any.

```
SELECT `events`.* 
FROM `events` INNER JOIN events_topics ON events.id = events_topics.event_id 
WHERE (events_topics.topic_id <> 75)
```

Comment: which SQL database you are using?

Comment: So, the 2nd query gives events that where topic_id = 75 and it shouldn't?

Comment: I'm using mysql and yes, the 2nd query is returning events where topic_id = 75. Just to note, I am using rails but this is a custom query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this means is that you have other `topic_id` values in `events_topic` for a given event. A.k.a., if you have `topic_id = 75` and `topic_id = 33` for, say, `eventid = 45,` this eventid will be returned because the query matches on `topic_id = 33`

You have asked:

> "give me all events where topic_id <> 75 does not exist"

Change the query to EXISTS/NOT EXISTS which is correct. This is:

> "give me all events where topic_id = 75 does not exist"

```
SELECT `events`.* 
FROM `events`
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM events_topics.event_id
            WHERE events_topics.topic_id = 75
                     AND
                      events.id = events_topics.event_id
            )


SELECT `events`.* 
FROM `events`
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM events_topics.event_id
            WHERE events_topics.topic_id = 75
                     AND
                      events.id = events_topics.event_id
            )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I knew my logic was lacking somewhere. Time to test it out.

Comment: question ... what's the difference between your response and x2's response?

Comment: @b_d: i think these 2 answers (and mine) give same results but may  differ in performance only: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null

Comment: @b_d: NOT IN and NOT EXISTS work the same mostly but EXISTS is more correct generally (eg if you have a NULL in the event_id list from events_topics then NOT IN fails).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
select * from Events
where id not in (select event_id from events_topics where topic_id=75)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt shows all events (topics are not shown) and just removes events-topics combinations with topic id=75. All other topics (with id<>75) are still there, so any event with a topic of 7 or 63 or whatever else will still be shown.

You only managed to not show events where their only topic has id 75.

But I think you want events that **none of their topics** has id=75:

```
SELECT events.* 
FROM events 
  LEFT JOIN events_topics
    ON events.id = events_topics.event_id
    AND events_topics.topic_id = 75
WHERE events_topics.event_id IS NULL
```

I think the above is equivalent with the `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` versions you have as answers. Their difference is only in matters of performance.

Comment: This will still give rows where topic_id = 33 as per my answer.

Comment: @gbn: I think not. My answer will show the same results with yours. I've included the `events_topics.topic_id = 75` condition in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` so it's the same as the `NOT EXISTS` solution.

Comment: You're right, please accept my apologies. I tend to use EXISTS mostly

Comment: @gbn: No problem. I agree that `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` is the worst of the 3 regarding clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try `'75'` instead of `75` :

```
SELECT `events`.*  
FROM `events` 
INNER JOIN events_topics ON events.id =        events_topics.event_id  
WHERE (events_topics.topic_id <> '75')
```

Comment: How is this different to what the was asked?

Comment: The '', found it sometimes usefull.

Comment: Ah, see it now. I didn't downvote but this won't be a solution: it's an EXISTS/IN type problem

Answer (score 0):

Your query not having any conflict but please make sure about data..And why you are having single quotes in besides event like this `events??

Check these

```
 select events.id from events where events.id <> 75
```

and

```
 select events_topics.event_id from events_topics where events_topics.event_id <> 75
```

If these are giving proper data then try this way

```
  SELECT events.* 
  FROM events
  INNER JOIN events_topics  ON events.id = events_topics.event_id and    
   events_topics.topic_id <> 75
```