# not getting expected result while joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want to display #acc that has no child here result must be B,C,D,E  but getting B,C,D only

```
create table #acc (mainid int,name nvarchar(20),subid int)

    insert into #acc values(1,'A',0)
    insert into #acc values(2,'B',1)
    insert into #acc values(3,'C',1)
    insert into #acc values(4,'D',1)
    insert into #acc values(5,'E',0)

    select  A.name from #acc
    A inner join #acc B
    on 
    A.subid   = B.mainid    

    drop table #acc
```

Comment: What's the difference between A and E? Why do you expect that you'd get E but not A?

Comment: @Juhana A has Child but E doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it

```
      select * from
        (select  A.mainid , A.name  from #acc
A left join #acc B
on A.subid   = B.mainid  ) as m where  m.mainid not in (select subid from #acc)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should rename the `subid` column to `superid` or `parentid` or something like that, because it is `B`, `C` & `D` that are *sub*-items of `A`, not the other way round. Maybe the inconsistent naming is exactly the reason why the results of your query seem incomprehensible to you or why you find it difficult to construct a query that returns the correct results.

Your query is essentially returning items that are some other items' children. They themselves may or may not have their own children. For example, if `B`, `C` or `D` had children, your query would return those children in addition to `B`, `C` and `D`. That does not seem exactly what you are after.

What you need here is not an inner join but an *anti*-join. It is when results are returned based on the fact that something has *not* matched. Anti-joins can be implemented in different ways:

1. Using `LEFT JOIN` + `IS NULL` check:

   ```
   SELECT A.*
   FROM #acc A
     LEFT JOIN #acc B ON A.mainid = B.subid
   WHERE B.mainid IS NULL
   ```

   Here we are joining the table to itself and returning the left side of the join where the right side have had no matches (i.e. returning rows with `mainid` values which are never found in the `subid` column).
2. Using `NOT EXISTS`:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM #acc A
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM #acc B
     WHERE A.mainid = B.subid
   )
   ```

   This query can be interpreted thus: return every row from `#acc` when there doesn't exist a match between that row's `mainid` and any other row's `subid`.
3. Using `NOT IN`:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM #acc
   WHERE mainid NOT IN (
     SELECT subid
     FROM #acc
   )
   ```

   This seems to me most straightforward (though not necessarily most efficient): return rows where `mainid` is not in the list of all existing `subid` values. If you used `NULL`s instead of `0` as root items' `subid` values, you'd also have to amend the last query by adding this filter to the subquery:

   ```
   …
   WHERE subid IS NOT NULL
   ```

   Otherwise it would work incorrectly.

You might also want to read this thread:

- [What's the difference between NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN vs. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null)