# How do I select a row from one table where the value row does not exist in another table?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have two identical tables, A and B, with the row "x".

I want to select all elements in A, where the value of x in A is not in any value of x of B.

How do I do that?

Comment: Sounds like `select '*' from A where not exists (select '*' from b where b.rowb = a.rowa)`

Comment: Give examples.  Data that shows what to return, when to return it, and when not to return it.

Comment: I won't add an answer because there are already answers suggesting `LEFT JOIN`, `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS` and `EXCEPT` (the 4 methods I would have suggested). Since you've not specified which DBMS you are using here is a link to another question regarding efficency of each method on various DBMS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB on TableA.X = TableB.X
WHERE TableB.X IS NULL
```

<sub>*(For the very straightforward example in your question, a `NOT EXISTS` / `NOT IN` approach is probably preferable, but is your real query is more complex, this is an option you might want to consider; if, for instace, you want som information from TableB where there is a match, but also want to know where there isn't one)*</sub>

Comment: Could you explain, in a little more detail, why this works? I don't get why the WHERE condition works. Why is TableB.X ever NULL? I have no NULL Values in my table.

Comment: @TravisG: This is how a `LEFT JOIN` works. In an `INNER JOIN` you would only receive the records where there is a `TableA.x <-> TableB.x` match. When doing a left (outer) join from `TableA`, you're saying that you want all the records from `TableA`, joined up with `TableB` where there is a match. For the records that doesn't match, every field from `TableB` will be reported as null in your select, even if the field in itself is marked as not nullable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having some trouble to understand what you need.
Anyway try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
WHERE x not IN (SELECT x FROM tableB)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from TableA
except
select *
from TableB
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest is the Left Join

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.X = B.X WHERE B.X IS NULL
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is not always fastest. It is DBMS specific. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null

Answer (score 1):

use it :

```
select * from a where x not in (select x from b)
```