# Select from table not in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, each with the following fields: `IDnumber`, `SectionNumber`, `Date`. There is overlapping information in the two tables.

How do I select only rows that do NOT overlap (ie. in one table but not the other)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `NOT IN` in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT IDnumber, SectionNumber, Date
FROM table1
WHERE IDnumber NOT IN (SELECT IDnumber FROM table2)
```

OR `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT IDnumber, SectionNumber, Date
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT IDnumber FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.IDnumber = t2.IDnumber)
```

Comment: +1. Or an `OUTER JOIN` and only return the rows with `NULL` values in the joined table. :-)

Comment: @user1572544 if this is helpful be sure to accept it as the answer via the checkmark on the left. :)

Comment: For sql server in particular, use `NOT EXISTS` if performance matters. Citation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null

Answer (score 1):

Which DBMS?

If SQL Server, then it's almost what you wrote in the title...

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE IDnumber NOT IN (SELECT IDnumber FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare multiple columns, you need an outer join:

```
select table1.*
from table1 left outer join
     table2
     on table1.id = table2.id and
        table1.SectionNumber = table2.SectionNumber and
        table1.date = table2.date
where table2.id is null
```

In the case where you might have many matches between the tables, then the join can be inefficient.  Assuming you only want those three fields, you can use a trick that avoids the join:

```
select id, SectionNumber, date
from ((select 0 as IsTable2, id, SectionNumber, date
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select 1 as IsTable2, id, SectionNumber, date
       from table2
      )
     ) t
 group by id, SectionNumber, date
 having max(isTable2) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.id is null
```