# Sql Queries To find unmatched data in many to many relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in the sql queries.

I've two table `Person_Table`  and `PersonAlias_Table`. In the first table **person_id** and **uniqe_id** are primary key and in the Alias Table also the **person_id** and uniqe_id along with **activity_code** are primary. I want to find the data which are in Alias table **but** not in person table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
  from PersonAlias_Table PA
       left outer join Person_Table P on PA.person_id = P.person_id 
       and PA.uniqe_id = P.uniqe_id
 where P.uniqe_id is null
```

Try this

Comment: Hi I understood the idea. May I know why we need to have the last where clause (where P.uniqe_id is null). I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: yeah the thing is left outer join will give you null values on right table for unmatched records. To filter out that we are using that null condition.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this depends on your DBMS, you can either use `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`

**NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    PersonAlias_Table pat
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Person_Table pt
            WHERE   pt.Person_ID = pat.Person_ID
            AND     pt.Uniqe_ID = pat.Uniqe_ID
        )
```

**LEFT JOIN/IS NULL**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    PersonAlias_Table pat
        LEFT JOIN Person_Table pt
            ON pt.Person_ID = pat.Person_ID
            AND pt.Uniqe_ID = pat.Uniqe_ID
WHERE    pt.Person_ID IS NULL
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246793/1048425) in MySQL `NOT EXISTS` is a little bit less efficient, In SQL Server `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` is less efficient, in PostgreSQL and Oracle both methods are the same, so it is really personal preference.