# SQL query with NOT IN returning no rows

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a sql statement as

```
select t.name, t.company from company t inner join employee e
on t.id = e.emp_id
where t.name not in(select t.name from table1 where t.id='x')
```

This above query returns no rows.

However, when I remove the sub query, and just use

```
select t.name, t.company from company t inner join employee e
    on t.id = e.emp_id
```

I get the required rows.

Also, the sub query

```
select t.name from table1 where t.id='x'
```

gives rows of data when executed by itself. Is my syntax for the `NOT IN` incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because `NOT IN (NULL)` is **always false**

```
select t.name, t.company from company t inner join employee e
on t.id = e.emp_id
where t.name not in(select null from dual)
```

would be the same.

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
select t.name, t.company 
from company t 
    join employee e on t.id = e.emp_id
where 
    not exists(select 1 from table1 t2 where t.name = t2.name)
and t.id='x'
```

follow up: [What's the difference between NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN vs. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2246772/1291428)

Comment: `t.name not in(t.name)`  is the issue here. This is never true.

Comment: this is because there's at least one `t.name` which is null.

Comment: You're missing the point. The query can never be true even with no NULLs in sight. `3 NOT IN (3)` is false.

Comment: you're right, he made a tipo also using the `t.` alias instead of using the other table alias. You'll notice I corrected that as well.

Comment: But that typo is in itself enough to cause the issue described so why the definite assertion that it is because `NOT IN (NULL)`?

Comment: You're right on that. I guess the `not exist` replacement is then pure prevention.

Answer (score 1):

A common cause is `NULL` values in the subquery.  But you have a different problem.  Here is your query:

```
select t.name, t.company
from company t inner join employee e
     on t.id = e.emp_id
where t.name not in(select t.name from table1 where t.id='x')
```

The `t.name` in the subquery refers to the "t" for `company` in the outer query.  That is, the query is checking for `t.name not in (t.name)` -- which is always false.  The subquery needs the `name` from  `table1`.  Using no alias fixes this:

```
select t.name, t.company
from company t inner join employee e
     on t.id = e.emp_id
where t.name not in(select name from table1 where id='x')
```

Better yet, use meaningful aliases (i.e. abbreviations of the table name) everywhere:

```
select c.name, c.company
from company c inner join employee e
     on c.id = e.emp_id
where c.name not in (select t1.name from table1 t1 where t1.id = 'x')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the poster accepted the wrong answer.  Yes there is an error in the query, the following should be changed from:

`where t.name not in(select t.name from table1`

to:

`where t.name not in(select t1.name from table1 t1`

However once that is done, the user's dilemma is still the same.  Using NOT EXISTS is a workaround but avoids the real issue.  The real solution is the one that was posted by [Taryn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/taryn), namely to add a filter in the subquery to exclude null values.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you might have `null` values in `table1`. If you have `null` values in `table1`, then you will want to explicitly exclude `null` in your WHERE NOT IN query:

```
select t.name, t.company 
from company t 
inner join employee e
  on t.id = e.emp_id
where t.name not in(select name 
                    from table1 
                    where id='x'
                       and name is not null);
```

You will also see that I removed the `t.` alias from the `WHERE` clause query.  You are using an alias that is associated with the outer table `company`. You will either need to change the alias name or remove it.