# Inner join Query for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Im Having 2 Tables 
 Table1

```
ID AnimalNAme  
1  Dog1    
1  Dog2    
2  cat1   
3  Cow1   
3  Cow2    
4  Rat1    
4  Rat2
```

Table2

```
ID AnimalNAme  
1  Dog1    
2  cat1   
3  Cow1   
4  Rat2
```

I need Output

```
1 Dog2  
3 Cow2   
4 Rat1
```

Comment: What is the condition for the desired output? There is no clear condition to filter out the list in the output.

Comment: its working fine error i was making is iwas using left join and  i had given Table1.AnimalName !=Table2.AnimalName 
and didnt specify "WHERE   Table2.ID IS NULL"

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  ID, AnimalName
FROM    Table1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Table2
            WHERE   Table1.ID = Table2.ID
            AND     Table1.AnimalName = Table2.AnimalName
        );
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a23a6/2)**

This will return all rows from table1 that do not exist in table 2.

It is however, worth noting that in MySQL `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` [generally performs better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246793/1048425) than `NOT EXISTS`, and has the same effect. By stating that `OUTERTABLE.Column IS NULL` you are limiting the query to rows where there is no corresponding item in the outer table.

```
SELECT  Table1.ID, Table1.AnimalName
FROM    Table1
        LEFT JOIN Table2
            ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
            AND Table1.AnimalName = Table2.AnimalName
WHERE   Table2.ID IS NULL;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a23a6/4)**

Comment: Rat2 Exists in both tables,

Comment: @Bere Exactly, the required output only contains items that are in table1 and **NOT** in table2

Answer (score 1):

It may be not the best option, but you can try the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.AnimalName = table1.AnimalName 
WHERE table2.AnimalName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Left join and check for non matches?

```
SELECT 
FROM Table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b
ON a.ID = b.ID
AND a.AnimalName = b.AnimalName
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question doesn't exactly state it, I can only guess by the data provided.  How can I get a list of all animals that are in the first table and not in the second.

Do a left-join to the table you are comparing against and do a check for NULL in the second table.

```
select
      t1.id,
      t1.animalName
   from
      Table1 t1
         left join table2 t2
            on t1.id = t2.id
           AND t1.animalName = t2.animalName
   where
      t2.id IS NULL
```

I'm doing left-join on BOTH columns since who knows the quality of the data and having multiple animal names by the same name, but under different IDs... such as ID associated with a pet's owner.