# MySQL - JOINS (excepts)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find 2 different result via JOINS.
Table look like;

```
SELECT id,member_id,registered_year FROM records;
```

I can listing which members registered in 2012 and also in 2013 with;

```
SELECT member_id FROM records a
INNER JOIN records b ON a.member_id=b.member_id
WHERE  a.registered_year='2013' AND b.registered_year='2012';
```

But I can't list revers of It. How can I list which members were registered in 2012 but not in 2013?

Thnx in advance.

Comment: If there is only one table named "records", there is no join necessary.

Comment: @Orin, I think (also from your answer) you don’t understand the structure of the table. It has several rows per member, one for each year.

Comment: Understood, thank you. Removed my answer to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT member_id FROM records a 
WHERE a.registered_year='2012' and  member_id not in 
(
  SELECT member_id FROM records
  WHERE registered_year='2013'
)
```

the inner select    `SELECT member_id FROM records WHERE registered_year='2013'` gets all users who where registered in 2013

the outer one gets all users that where not in the inner select who where registered in 2012

Comment: `WHERE a.registered_year='2013'` --- will always be falsy!!! "does not answer the question !" (c)

Comment: yep - bad copy paste - fixed

Comment: It's interesting how mysql would optimize this. `member_id not in ` would definitely cause a scan, but would it perform a huge nested `select` "everything" for every row

Comment: good read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null on performance diffs - you can always check with explain for the particular query

Comment: bookmarked it thanks. PS: an article about optimizer behaviour may become a bit inactual after 4 years :-S

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT member_id
  FROM records a
 WHERE registered_year = 2012
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null
                     FROM records b
                    WHERE a.member_id = b.member_id
                      AND b.registered_year = 2013)
```

Answer (score 1):

For users which are not in both tables, you can use a left join rather than an inner join and then test for null.

Example:

```
SELECT a.member_id 
FROM records a
  LEFT JOIN records b ON  a.member_id = b.member_id
                      AND b.registered_year = '2013' 
WHERE a.registered_year = '2012' 
  AND b.registered_year IS NULL;
```

Comment: With this way, also listing 2010, 2011s too. I only need registered in 2012 and not registered in 2013s.

Comment: it shouldnt be ? Can you post an example on SQLfiddle ?

Comment: Should be `ON a.member_id=b.member_id AND b.registered_year='2013' WHERE ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is usually solved with `NOT EXISTS` (or the equivalent `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `NOT IN` constructions.) In this particular case, there is a way with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT member_id 
FROM records
WHERE registered_year IN (2012, 2013)
GROUP BY member_id
HAVING MAX(registered_year) = 2012 ;
```

I doubt this will be efficient but you can test along with the other versions.

Comment: "registered in 2012 but **not in** 2013"

Comment: @zerkms: Yes. That's what it does. And the MIN comparison is redundant.