# Difference between two recordsets in TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, notin

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and we have two tables called **Applications** and **Enrolments**.  I want to know which applications are not converted into the Enrolments.  As shown in the following figure.

I tried to use NOT IN but it works only with the single column.  I have 2 columns to compare.  Could you please advise me what is the most appropriate way?  Thanks.

PS.  I cannot change the structure of the database and they are from third party vendor.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way, using **[except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)**

```
select  
        StudentID, 
        CourseID
FROM dbo.Applications
except
select  
        StudentID, 
        CourseID
FROM dbo.Enrolments
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead:

```
SELECT StudentID, CourseID
FROM dbo.Applications a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM Enrolments e
    WHERE e.StudenID = a.StudenID 
    AND   e.CourseID = a.CourseID
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Applications a
LEFT JOIN Enrolments e 
       ON e.StudentId = a.StudentId
      AND e.CourseId = a.CourseId
WHERE e.StudentId IS NULL
```

Side note: interesting answer comparing similar solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246793/1114171)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* FROM Applications a
LEFT JOIN Enrolments e 
   ON a.StudentID = e.StudentID AND a.CourseID = e.CourseID
WHERE e.StudentID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is probably a left join between applications and enrolments - returning just the ones where the enrolment is null

IE

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Applications a
LEFT JOIN Enrolments e ON a.StudentID = e.StudentID AND a.CourseID = e.CourseID
WHERE e.StudentID IS NULL
```