# sql subquery issue with inner join

Tags: sql

I've got these tables in my database:

**Tourist** - this is the first table

```
Tourist_ID - primary key
name...etc...
```

**EXTRA_CHARGES**

```
Extra_Charge_ID - primary key 
Extra_Charge_Description
Amount
```

**Tourist_Extra_Charges**

```
Tourist_Extra_Charge_ID
Extra_Charge_ID - foreign key
Tourist_ID - foreign key
```

---

So here is the example

I've one Tourist with  Tourist_ID - 86 . This tourist with id 86 has extra charges with Extra_Charge_ID - 7 and and Extra_charge_ID - 11;

I try to make a query so I can take the name of the Tourist and all the charges in EXTRA_CHARGES table that **doesn't**  belong to this tourist.

Here is the query that I try - but it doesn't return nothing.

```
SELECT
    Tourist.Name
    , EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description
    , EXTRA_CHARGES.Amount 
FROM 
    Tourist 
    INNER JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES 
        ON Tourist.Tourist_ID = TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID 
    INNER JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES 
        ON TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID 
WHERE
    Tourist.Tourist_ID= 86 
    and EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID NOT IN
    (   SELECT Extra_Charge_ID 
        FROM TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES te
        WHERE te.Tourist_ID = 86
    )
```

I of course can get only the charges with this query

```
SELECT * FROM EXTRA_CHARGES e
WHERE e.Extra_Charge_ID NOT IN
 (SELECT Extra_Charge_ID from TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES te

  WHERE te.Tourist_ID = 86
 )
```

but I can't find a way to get the name of this tourist

Comment: can you show an output of your query to give as more understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two options, both are pretty much the same, but [one may perform better than the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null) depending on your DBMS.

The principal of both is the same, get a cross join of tourist and extra charges so you have all extra charges for all tourists, then use either `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` to eliminate all extra charges that the tourist has:

```
SELECT  Tourist.Name,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Amount 
FROM    Tourist
        CROSS JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES
WHERE   Tourist.Tourist_ID= 86 
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES
            WHERE   TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = Tourist.Tourist_ID
            AND     TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID
        );


SELECT  Tourist.Name,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Amount 
FROM    Tourist
        CROSS JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES
        LEFT JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES
            ON TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = Tourist.Tourist_ID
            AND TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID
WHERE   Tourist.Tourist_ID = 86 
AND     TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_Extra_Charge_ID IS NULL;
```

---

**EDIT**

Since the two criteria you are applying are logically different, you need to use two queries to get it. The first is as before, the extra charges that a tourist does not have, and the second is for tourists who have all extra charges

```
SELECT  Tourist.Name,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Amount 
FROM    Tourist
        CROSS JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES
        LEFT JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES
            ON TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = Tourist.Tourist_ID
            AND TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID
WHERE   Tourist.Tourist_ID = 1 
AND     TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_Extra_Charge_ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT  Tourist.Name,
        NULL,
        NULL
FROM    Tourist
        CROSS JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES
        LEFT JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES
            ON TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = Tourist.Tourist_ID
            AND TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID
WHERE   Tourist.Tourist_ID = 1 
GROUP BY Tourist.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_Extra_Charge_ID);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28665/7)**

Comment: how whathappens in the first case when the tourist has all of the charges so - query will return no row. but I need the name - even if they  have no extra_charges

Answer (score 1):

You may include the tourist name (for Tourist_ID=86) as a subquery in the select statement:

```
SELECT (SELECT Tourist.Name FROM Tourist WHERE Tourist_ID=86) TouristName, e.*
FROM   EXTRA_CHARGES e
WHERE  e.Extra_Charge_ID NOT IN
       (SELECT Extra_Charge_ID 
        FROM   TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES te
        WHERE  te.Tourist_ID = 86
       )
```

Comment: Hey it works, but when I get the name on the column - it's written "no column name".Do you know how to get it

Comment: Probably you have omitted the column name. Write like `(SELECT ....) AS TouristName`

Comment: Yes I was so tired that I really omitted it :) Thans

Answer (score 1):

You may try this it's more efficient:

```
SELECT t.Name 
FROM Tourist t JOIN 
 (SELECT * FROM EXTRA_CHARGES e 
 JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGE tec ON e.Extra_Charge_ID = tec.Extra_Charge_ID AND tec.TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES != 86)
WHERE t.Tourist_ID = 86
```

btw. you do not need Tourist_Extra_Charge_ID column in Tourist_Extra_Charges

Comment: I thought the OP also require EXTRA_CHARGES columns with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `INNER JOIN ... ON .. <> ...`

```
SELECT
    Tourist.Name
    , EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description
    , EXTRA_CHARGES.Amout 
FROM 
    Tourist 
    INNER JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES 
        ON Tourist.Tourist_ID <> TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID 
    INNER JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES 
        ON TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID 
WHERE
    Tourist.Tourist_ID= 86
```

See here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28665/2