# Looking to remove the subquery

Tags: mysql

This query works for me, but I don't want to use a subquery. I tried a lot but failed can I use this query without a subquery?

```
select a1.active_id
from active_table a1
where a1.active_id
NOT IN ( select a2.active_id from view a2 group by a2.active_id )
AND datediff(now(),active_date)>30
```

Comment: I suggest you set the datediff first. Only the rows that will match that will be checked against the `NOT IN()`, which should be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select a1.`active_id`
 from active_table a1 
          left join view a2 on (a1.`active_id` = a2.active_id)
where a2.active_id is null
  AND datediff(now(),a1.active_date)>30
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a1.active_id FROM active_table a1 
LEFT JOIN view a2
ON a1.active_id = a2.active_id
WHERE a2.active IS NULL
AND datediff(now(),active_date)>30
```

LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is equivalent to NOT IN. For detailed explanation see:

[What's the difference between NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN vs. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null)