# Delete all rows which has no id existing in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-relations

I want to delete all rows which has no existing foreign key in another table
example:

```
table1
+----+-------+
|id  | data  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | hi    |
+----+-------+
| 2  | hi    |
+----+-------+
| 3  | hi    |
+----+-------+
| 4  | hi    |
+----+-------+
| 5  | hi    |
+----+-------+

table2
+----+-------+
|a_id| data  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | hi    |
+----+-------+
| 20 | hi    |
+----+-------+
| 3  | hi    |
+----+-------+
| 40 | hi    |
+----+-------+
| 5  | hi    |
+----+-------+
```

The **query** will delete rows with id# 20 and 40 on table2.

I need to do this so that i could establish a relationship with table1 and table2.

Comment: `Delete From Tab2 where ID not in (Select ID From Tab1)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DELETE table2 
FROM   table2 
       LEFT JOIN table1 
              ON table2.a_id = table1.id 
WHERE  table1.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

To sum up, there are tree ways to delete multi tables

1. `NOT IN(SELECT ...)` - @someone (he had deleted his answer)

   ```
   Delete From Tab2 where ID not in (Select ID From Tab1)
   ```
2. `LEFT JOIN` - @eggyal

   ```
   DELETE table2
   FROM   table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.a_id = table1.id
   WHERE  table1.id IS NULL
   ```
3. `NOT EXISTS`

   ```
   DELETE
   FROM  table2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM table1
     WHERE table1.id = table2.a_id
   )
   ```

According to [What's the difference between NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN vs. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null), different RDBMS perform differently.