# MySQL: Update rows in table, from rows with matching key in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `users` with existing data, and I upload updated data to a temporary table `users_temp`.

I am trying to create two queries, one to update `name` and `department_id` rows in `users` with data from `users_temp` on matching `id`.

And another to remove rows in `users` which don't have matching `id` in `users_temp`.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update users
inner join users_temp using (id)
set users.name = users_temp.name,
users.department_id = users_temp.department_id

delete from users
where not exists (select * from users_temp where users_temp.id = users.id)
```

Comment: Why use `LEFT JOIN` if you're just going to filter out the non-matching rows in the `WHERE` clause? Use an `INNER JOIN` so they're not included in the firstplace.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Could you please add a query that copies a row from users_temp into users if it doesn't exist in users?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding a join in your update.

```
UPDATE users u 
INNER JOIN users_temp ut on u.id = ut.id //or whatever the matching fields are
SET u.name = ut.name, u.department_id = ut.department_id;
```

I'm sure someone will have a more efficient example for the second query but this would do the trick:

[Delete all rows which has no id existing in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462374/delete-all-rows-which-has-no-id-existing-in-another-table)