# Mysql "No Database selected" error when using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete from table1 if ID does not exist in table2 in Mysql.

When using **sql query in Phpmyadmin**

```
DELETE t1 FROM db.table1 t1 LEFT JOIN db.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

it works perfectly deleting from table1 rows not found in table2 !

However when using **same sql in PHP** as

```
mysqli_query($connection,"DELETE t1 FROM db.table1 t1 LEFT JOIN db.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

it throws error **No database selected** . I have verified and my connections are defined properly with host,username and password.

`$connection = @mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password);`

I do not think that $connection is problem as there are other queries before/after it which all work perfectly ! What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have added $connection details

Comment: I am using database.table in my query hence not selecting database separately . Thanks for help though

Comment: Your are not selecting any database. Please connect the  MySQL with the database name.please look at below i have posted the answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working ! I still fail to understand why the PHP Query fails. Anyways, the query itself was simple which I copied from SO question [Delete all rows which has no id existing in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462374/delete-all-rows-which-has-no-id-existing-in-another-table).

What i could make out is that using alias was problematic and finally I used full table name with DB and it worked perfectly. I am pretty sure that alias can be used, its just that I am not expert in them !

`mysqli_query($connection,"DELETE db.table1 FROM db.table1 LEFT JOIN db.table2 ON table1.id = table2.id WHERE table2.id IS NULL");`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you passed the db name you wanted to use:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: I am using `database.table` in my query hence not selecting database separately . Thanks for help though

Answer (score 0):

Please specify your database with the connection.

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

Here you are no passing the database name in your connection .

Or

in your query itself specify the db name eg :- db.table

Use this way also.

Please try any of  this. This will work in your case.