# Compare two MySQL tables and remove rows that no longer exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created a system using PHP/MySQL that downloads a large XML dataset, parses it and then inserts the parsed data into a MySQL database every week.

This system is made up of two databases with the same structure. One is a production database and one is a temporary database where the data is parsed and inserted into first.

When the data has been inserted into the temporary database I perform a merge by inserting/replacing the data in the production database. I have done all of the above so far. I then realised, data that might have been removed in a new dataset will be left to linger in the production database.

I need to perform a check to see if the new data is still in the production database, if it is then leave it, if it isn't delete the row from the production database so that the rows aren't left to linger.

For arguments sake, let's say the two databases are called `database_temporary` and `database_production`.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: How are you merging the data? If via SQL, A simple SQL can do the delete (`delete from table where pk not in (select pk from temp)`)

Comment: @Nivas Sorry, I should have said, yes it is using SQL. If it's as simple as that maybe you could post it as an answer? Thanks :D

Comment: If you're going to use a NOT IN clause, probably you should use a timestamp column for performance. It should check only the rows that you didn't check before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL to merge, a simple SQL can do the delete as well:

```
delete from database_production.table
where pk not in (select pk from database_temporary.table)
```

Notes:

- This assumes that there is a a row can be uniquely identified. This may be based on a single column, multiple columns or another mechanism.
- If your dataset is large, a `not exists` mey perform better than `not in`. See [What's the difference between NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN vs. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null) and [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

An example `not exists`:

```
delete from database_production.table p
where not exists (select 1 from database_temporary.table t where t.pk = p.pk)
```

Performance Notes:
As pointed out by @mgonzalez in the comments on the question, you may want to use a timestamp column (something like last modified) for comparing/merging in general so that you vompare only changed rows. This does not apply to the delete specifically, you cannot use timestamp for the delete because, well, the row would not exist.

Comment: Could you provide a `not exists` as example as well please? I suppose it depends how large, the databases in question both consist of around 20 million rows each