# Not exist in anyone

Tags: sql

I want to make a query where I select all the IDs of table A, which ids will connect to existing values of end_date in table B. 
I need to get the IDs of table A which will connect only to finished IDs(i.e. with existing end_date) on B table. 
Relation of table a and b is one to many . A can correlate to many Bs . B will always correlate to one A table.

I have made something like this:

```
select id 
from A 
where not exists 
(select 1 
from B 
where end_date is null 
and A.id=B.id)
```

Is this correct? Or is there a faster query for the same thing?

`EDIT:` end_date is in table B

example :
In the data set:

```
A.id=1
B.id=1
B.bid=333 
B.end_date=null 

A.id=1
B.id=1
B.bid=334 
B.end_date=05/05/2014 

A.id=2
B.id=2
B.bid=335 
B.end_date=null 

A.id=2
B.id=2
B.bid=336 
B.end_date=null 


A.id=3
B.id=3
B.bid=337
B.end_date=04/04/2014 

A.id=3
B.id=3
B.bid=338 
B.end_date=04/04/2014`
```

My query should result only id=3.

Comment: what you have is correct and imho expresses your intent most clearly, for more info about the differences between `not exists`, `not in` and `left join` see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2246772/3574819

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table structure is

```
A(id)

B(id, end_date)
```

Then to select all A.id where there is no b.end_date (or it is null) you can use this query

```
Select id
From   A
Where  id Not In (Select id From B Where end_date is Not Null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a `LEFT JOIN` like

```
select A.id 
from A a
left join B b
on a.id = b.id
and b.end_date is not null 
where b.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your DBMS, but in later versions of SQL Server, this might be faster.  You will have to test based on your data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.End_date IS NOT NULL
EXCEPT
SELECT B.ID
WHERE b.End_date IS NULL
```

`EXCEPT` is a set operator that returns all entries in the first set that don't exist in the second set.  Doing the query this way gives you two SARGable `WHERE` clauses rather than one nonSARGable subquery, so it could end up faster depending on your data topography and your physical indexes.