# SQL query to check if value doesn't exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query which does most of what I need it to do but I'm running into a problem.

There are 3 tables in total. `entries`, `entry_meta` and `votes`.

I need to get an entire row from `entries` when `competition_id = 420` in the `entry_meta` table and the ID either doesn't exist in `votes` or it does exist but the `user_id` column value isn't 1.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT entries.* FROM entries 
INNER JOIN entry_meta ON (entries.ID = entry_meta.entry_id)
WHERE 1=1 
    AND ( ( entry_meta.meta_key = 'competition_id' AND CAST(entry_meta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '420') ) 
GROUP BY entries.ID 
ORDER BY entries.submission_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

The votes table has 4 columns. vote_id, entry_id, user_id, value.

One option I was thinking of was to `SELECT entry_id FROM votes WHERE user_id = 1` and include it in an `AND` clause in my query. Is this acceptable/efficient?

E.g.

```
AND entries.ID NOT IN (SELECT entry_id FROM votes WHERE user_id = 1)
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  It looks reasonable, although you might want to read about [NOT EXISTS vs NOT IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks Andrew. Sometimes actually writing the problem down in order to explain it clarifies the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

A `left join` with an appropriate `where` clause might be useful:

```
SELECT 
    entries.* 
FROM 
    entries 
    INNER JOIN entry_meta ON (entries.ID = entry_meta.entry_id)
    LEFT JOIN votes ON entries.ID = votes.entry_id
WHERE 1=1 
  AND (
      entry_meta.meta_key = 'competition_id' 
      AND CAST(entry_meta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '420') 
      AND votes.entry_id IS NULL -- This will remove any entry with votes
  ) 
GROUP BY entries.ID 
ORDER BY entries.submission_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of Andrew's suggestion to use exists / not exists.

```sql
select
  e.*
from
  entries e
  join entry_meta em on e.ID = em.entry_id
where
  em.meta_key = 'competition_id'
  and cast(em.meta_value as char) = '420'
  and (
    not exists (
      select 1
      from votes v
      where
        v.entry_id = e.ID
    )
    or exists (
      select 1
      from votes v
      where
        v.entry_id = e.ID
        and v.user_id != 1
    )
  )
group by e.ID
order by e.submission_date desc
limit 0, 25;
```

Note: it's generally not a good idea to put a function inside a where clause (due to performance reasons), but since you're also joining on IDs you should be OK.

Also, The left join suggestion by Barranka may cause the query to return more rows than your are expecting (assuming that there is a 1:many relationship between entries and votes).