# SQL query to find list of primary keys not used

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to make a drop down picker in an Access database to display all the primary keys not used, in this case a date that is limited to the first of the month.

I have 2 tables that are for this use

```
tblReport 
pk date  |  Data for this record |
05/01/13 |     stuff
06/01/13 |     stuff
07/01/13 |     stuff
08/01/13 |     stuff
```

and

```
tblFutureDates
pk date  |  an index
05/01/13 |     1
06/01/13 |     2
07/01/13 |     3
08/01/13 |     4
09/01/13 |     5
10/01/13 |     6
11/01/13 |     7
12/01/13 |     8
```

I want a query that looks at these two tables and returns the dates that are in the second table that aren't in the first one. I have tried some joins but cannot figure it out. This is what I have thus far:

```
SELECT tblFutureDates.FutureDate
FROM tblFutureDates RIGHT JOIN tblReport 
ON tblFutureDates.FutureDate = tblReport.ReportMonth;
```

and that returns:

```
05/01/13
06/01/13
07/01/13
08/01/13
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selects dates from `tblFutureDates` that are `NOT IN` `tblReport`

```
SELECT tblFutureDates.FutureDate
FROM tblFutureDates 
WHERE tblFutureDates.FutureDate
NOT IN (SELECT tblReport.ReportMonth FROM tblReport)
```

You can also use `LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL` and `NOT EXISTS` for more information about all 3 see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null).

Comment: That did it, I added `TOP 16` to the select to limit the list for my drop down. Thanks