# SQL Join Not Exists

Tags: sql

I have the following between these two tables, id column and case column

```
  Left Table                Right Table
| id1 | case#1 |          | case#1 | id1 |  
| id2 | case#1 |          | case#1 | id3 |
| id3 | case#2 |          | case#2 | id1 |
```

As you can see `case#1` is not assigned to `id2` on the right table, therefore I would like to pull  the `(id2, case#1)` record from the left table.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Left join.. select a.id, a.case,b.id, b.case from leftable a left join  rightable b on a.id=b.id and a.case=b.case

Answer (score 1):

You would need to perform an OUTER JOIN with a multiple JOIN condition:

```
   left_table as l right outer join right_table as r
   on l.id = r.id and l.case_ = r.case_
   where l.id IS NULL;
```

This will return non-matching rows from the left table

Comment: an inner join is giving me matches

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a left join?

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN table ON table1.field1 = table2.field2
```

Depends on what you want.  If you do INNER JOIN, you get the rows that match in Table1 AND Table2.  If you do OUTER JOIN, you get all of Table1 and only the matching rows from Table2.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `LEFT JOIN` and selected the record with `NULL` id in the Right Table using `WHERE` clause. See my query and demo below:

```
SELECT 
      *
FROM LeftTable A
LEFT JOIN RightTable B ON A.id=B.id 
WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45a57/28/0)**

Answer (score 0):

I would use NOT EXISTS operation in that case.

```
    SELECT  l.id, l.value
    FROM    LeftTable l
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RightTable r WHERE r.id = l.id and r.case_value = l.case_value)
```

Efficiency comparing and the difference between NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN vs. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null)