# Using Not IN SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in which I'm trying to find how many customers from one database exist in another.

```
select customerid 
from transactions 
where dtcreated > '5/2/14'  in (Select customerid 
                                from database2.dbo.customers 
                                where dtcreated > '3/1/14')
Group by customerid
```

This query works just fine. But obviously, some customers did not have transactions in the time period I'm searching for in the transactions. I'm trying to find those customer ID's.

I've tried:

```
Select customerid 
from database2.dbo.customers 
where dtcreated > '3/1/14' NOT IN (select customerid 
                                   from transactions 
                                   where dtcreated > '5/2/14')
group by customerid
```

But this query doesn't return any results.

Comment: convert that string to date if you want meaningful results

Comment: The customer IDs in each Database are identical?

Comment: where Cast(dtcreated as datetime) >Cast('3/1/14' as datetime)

Comment: No difference. dtcreated column is of type datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not getting result because of the fact that there is a **NULL     value** in the customer id column.

```
 Select distinct customerid 
    from database2.dbo.customers 
    where dtcreated> '2014-01-03' and 
    customerid NOT IN 
              (
                 select customerid 
                 from transactions 
                 where dtcreated > '2014-02-05' and 
                 trim(customerid) is not null
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither query should work as you have them right now. You haven't specified  which field is in/not in the sub-query. Modify it to something like this

```
Select c.customerid from database2.dbo.customers c where c.dtcreated > '3/1/14' and c.customerid NOT  in
    (

    select customerid from transactions where created > '5/2/14'
    )
    group by c.customerid
```

Comment: Same problem.  No results.

Comment: When you run your subquery by itself do you get results? Also, can you use datetime variables instead of strings?

Comment: I could, but the dtcreated column is of type dtcreated, so that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If your customer ids are the same, you can do an inner join on the table and then just filter down to the result set you want. Should be a better way to achieve the intersection you are asking for.

```
select database2.dbo.customers.customerid
from transactions trans
   INNER join database2.dbo.customers
      on trans.customerid = database2.dbo.customers.customerid
where trans.dtcreated < '5/2/14' 
   and database2.dbo.customers.dtcreated > '3/1/14'

Group by database2.dbo.customers.customerid
```

Apparently there is a keyword for this type of operation

```
SELECT customerid
FROM transactions
WHERE dtcreated < '5/2/14' 

INTERSECT

SELECT customerid
FROM database2.dbo.customers
WHERE dtcreated > '3/1/14'
```

Comment: You should add *at least* two or three sentences to *explain* what you're suggesting, and why ...

Answer (score 0):

I think Problem is Due to `date` formats use this:

```
Select customerid 
from database2.dbo.customers 
where CAST(dtcreated  as DATE) > '2014-01-03' NOT IN (select customerid 
                                   from transactions 
                                   where CAST(dtcreated  as DATE) > '2014-02-05')
group by customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to correct the syntax for both of your queries. Based on what I am interpreting that you are trying do:

```
Select customerid 
from database2.dbo.customers 
where dtcreated > '3/1/14' 
and customerid NOT IN (select customerid 
                       from transactions 
                       where dtcreated > '5/2/14')
```

Whichever field you return in your subquery should return the field you are saying 'not in' for. In addition since you are only returning customer ids, you don't need the group by at the end. This will return customers a dbo.customers recorded with a date later than '3/1/14'  that are not in the transactions table with a date greater than '5/2/14'. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Another alternative that might be useful for you is 'not exists' Not Exists sometime has better performance. for more details see: [What's the difference between NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN vs. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null)

this would look like :

```
Select customerid 
from database2.dbo.customers c
where dtcreated > '3/1/14' 
and not exists(select *                           
               from transactions t
               where dtcreated > '5/2/14'
               and c.customerid  = t.customerid
               )
```