# How can i optimize this mysql query ? i use IN() operator

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

How can I optimize this mysql query? I'm using the `IN()` operator, but I believe it's not the way to do it.

```
select * 
from users 
where usid NOT in 
(
select usid 
from images 
where status=0
) 
and us_status=0
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2246772/1048425) and more importantly [this link](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) in the accepted answer should help you out here. In summary, for MySQL use `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` to remove matching records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN images ON user.usid = images.usid AND images.status = 0
WHERE images.usid IS NULL
AND us_status = 0
```

This avoids using IN which can perform poorly.

Comment: Thanks very much, just instead us_status must be users.status yes?

Comment: Your original query had us_status in it. If that was a typo for user.status then change it to that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN images ON users.usid = images.usid AND images.status=1 AND images.usid IS NOT NULL
WHERE users.us_status = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query :

```
SELECT us.* 
FROM users  as us
INNER JOIN images as img ON us.usid = img.usid AND img.status=1
WHERE us.us_status = 0
```

Must read the article : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp