# Query Help Between Date Range, but Not Recent

Tags: mysql

I'm know this can be written as a single SQL statement, but I just don't know how to do it. I have two separate queries. Ont that pulls all orders from a specific period of last year

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE date_added BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-11-01';
```

and one that pulls from the last month

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND Now() ORDER BY date_added ASC
```

What I want to do is now join the two so that I only get the customer_id of orders that were placed inside of the date range last year (query 1), but haven't placed an order in the last month (query 2).

I know there is a way to set this up as a join, but my knowledge on sql join's is not very limited. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35ed0/1

```
SELECT * FROM `order` 
WHERE date_added BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-11-01'
   AND customer_id NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT customer_id  FROM `order` 
   WHERE date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND Now())
```

**UPDATE** If you need only 1 records per customer_id, here is [an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/368af/8) . It is not very best from performance perspective. But it returns only last (according to the `date_added` column) order per customer.

```
SELECT t.*,
   if(@fltr=customer_id, 0, 1) fltr,
   @fltr:=customer_id
FROM (SELECT *
  FROM `order` 
  WHERE date_added BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-11-01'
    AND customer_id NOT IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT customer_id  FROM `order` 
     WHERE date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND Now())
  ORDER BY customer_id, date_added DESC
) t
HAVING (fltr=1);
```

Comment: This works well and is very concise. How does NOT IN compare to NOT EXIST?

Comment: that is almost no difference on your case. I like `NOT IN`, it seems more clean and logical to me.

Comment: I noticed this actually produces duplicates of the same customer ID if there is more than one match. Does the DISTINCT not work to narrow this down to only unique customer_id's?

Comment: If you just need distinct customer_id. change `SELECT *`  to `SELECT DISTINCT customer_id`. I did `*` becuase you wrote in your OP that firs query was `SELECT *`

Comment: With MySQL `not in` should perform slightly better than `not exists` according to [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null?lq=1) (which might be outdated).

Comment: I would like to select the whole table * but only include 1 result per customer_id. So if they placed 3 orders last year but none in the past month they only get added once.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a correlated `not exists` predicate for this as I feel that it corresponds well with the intent of the question:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `order` o1
WHERE date_added BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-11-01'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM `order` o2
    WHERE date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW() 
      AND o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id
);
```

Comment: This worked good. Couple questions. what is the 1 for in the second select? I was confused by that also could I add Distinct to the first select to only get unique Customer ID's?

Comment: @user3167249 The `1` is just used to signify that the result returned from the subquery isn't important as the `exists` predicate only evaluates if any result is returned, not what it is. You could just as well use `*` or some column. I just think it's clearer this way. As for the `distinct` - yes, if you only want unique customers you can do `select distinct o1.customer_id` instead for example.

Answer (score 0):

I like to approach these questions using `group by` and `having`.  You are looking for customer ids, so:

```
select o.customer_id
from orders o
group by o.customer_id
having sum(date_added BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-11-01') > 0 and
       sum(date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND Now()) = 0;
```

Comment: This produced results that were outside of my time period.

Comment: @user3167249 . . . I don't understand your comment.  This can only return customers who have at least one purchase in the 2014 time period and none in the most recent month.