# Alternate way of Not exists in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I using the below Query which took long time to execute since it got 2 million records

```
DELETE  
AC 
FROM 
SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST AC
INNER JOIN SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST_REF CR ON        AC.CHECKLIST_REF_ID   =      CR.CHECKLIST_REF_ID 
INNER JOIN SGT_APPLICATION APP ON APP.APPLICATION_ID = AC.APPLICATION_ID
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST SAC
WHERE SAC.APPLICATION_ID = AC.APPLICATION_ID AND
APP.APP_CATEGORY_VALUE = CR.APP_CATEGORY_VALUE
AND APP.APP_SUB_CATEGORY_VALUE = CR.APP_SUB_CATEGORY_VALUE
)
```

So What is the alternate way of instead "not exists"

Comment: 1 - define slow. 2- 2 million records to be deleted could be "slow" for many reasons like triggers, cascades, large data, indexes being updated, etc. Have you looked at any of this? 3 - by 2 million do you mean 2 million to filter from and delete some or 2 million being deleted total? 4 - Before trying to rewrite the query, have you looked at the query plan to see why it might be slow? Once you have that you should include it.

Comment: You probably just need the appropriate indexes on the tables.

Comment: Convert inner query to `LEFT JOIN` s with `IS NULL` ?  Though modern query optimizers would probably try something like this by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
--DELETE AC 
SELECT * -- So you can quickly copy&paste to try. :)
FROM 
SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST AC
INNER JOIN SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST_REF CR ON AC.CHECKLIST_REF_ID = CR.CHECKLIST_REF_ID 
INNER JOIN SGT_APPLICATION APP ON APP.APPLICATION_ID = AC.APPLICATION_ID AND APP.APP_CATEGORY_VALUE = CR.APP_CATEGORY_VALUE AND APP.APP_SUB_CATEGORY_VALUE = CR.APP_SUB_CATEGORY_VALUE
LEFT JOIN SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST SAC ON SAC.APPLICATION_ID = AC.APPLICATION_ID 
WHERE SAC.APPLICATION_ID IS NULL
```

Although theoretically NOT EXISTS seems to be [the best option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null).

But why did you put those conditions between APP and CR inside the subquery? I moved them to the corresponding `INNER JOIN`, but you have to verify that works.

Answer (score 0):

I bet a left outer join will be more performant than Exists in this case.

```
DELETE  
    AC 
    FROM 
    SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST AC
    INNER JOIN SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST_REF CR ON        AC.CHECKLIST_REF_ID   =      CR.CHECKLIST_REF_ID 
    INNER JOIN SGT_APPLICATION APP ON APP.APPLICATION_ID = AC.APPLICATION_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST CR2 ON CR2.APPLICATION_ID = AC.APPLICATION_ID AND APP.APP_CATEGORY_VALUE = CR2.APP_CATEGORY_VALUE AND APP.APP_SUB_CATEGORY_VALUE = CR2.APP_SUB_CATEGORY_VALUE
    WHERE 
    NOT CR2.APPLICATION_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all move conditions
APP.APP_CATEGORY_VALUE = CR.APP_CATEGORY_VALUE 
and APP.APP_SUB_CATEGORY_VALUE = CR.APP_SUB_CATEGORY_VALUE
out of subquery because they have nothing to do with that subquery.
You can join on many parameteres.

```
Join .... on A = B AND C = D
```

Now, about your question, assuming you have cleaned your subquery then
do it like that

```
select/delete .... 
FROM 
SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST AC
INNER JOIN SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST_REF CR ON        AC.CHECKLIST_REF_ID   =      CR.CHECKLIST_REF_ID 
INNER JOIN SGT_APPLICATION APP ON APP.APPLICATION_ID = AC.APPLICATION_ID
.... other joins and changes i mentioned, etc...
LEFT JOIN SGT_APPLICATION_CHECKLIST as SAC 
ON SAC.APPLICATION_ID = AC.APPLICATION_ID
where SAC.APPLICATION_ID IS NOT NULL
```

to get only the records that joined with your SAC.