# insert into one table from another

Tags: sql

I want to insert some data of column1 from Table_B to Table_A if the data in Table_B does not exist in Table_A. For example, 'Headache' is in column1 of Table_B but not in column1 of Table_A.  Thanks. I wrote the SQL below, but it did not work:

```
insert into Table_A(column1)
select column1
from Table_B
where column1 not in (select column1 from Table_A)
```

Comment: What do yo mean by *"did not work"*? Can you elaborate? Did you get an error? Also, what DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A(column1)
SELECT B.column1
FROM Table_B B
LEFT JOIN Table_A A ON B.column1 = A.column1
WHERE A.column1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into Table_A(column1)
select column1 from Table_B 
left join Table_A  on Table_B.column1 = Table_A.column1
where A.column1 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

With no sample data it is hard to say for sure, but my best guess would be that you have a `NULL` value in `table_A.Column1`. if you did have a null values, your query would be equivalent to something like:

```
SELECT  Column1
FROM    Table_B
WHERE   Column1 NOT IN (1, 2, 3, NULL);
```

Which is equivalent of:

```
SELECT  Column1
FROM    Table_B
WHERE   Column1 <> 1
AND     Column1 <> 2
AND     Column1 <> 3
AND     Column1 <> NULL;
```

Since `Column1 <> NULL` is not true, the query returns no results. The most syntactically similar way to achieve the desired result where you might have NULL columns is using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A(column1)
SELECT  Column1
FROM    Table_B AS B
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_A AS A WHERE A.Column1 = B.Column1);
```

However, another method you could use is:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A(column1)
SELECT  Column1
FROM    Table_B AS B
        LEFT JOIN Table_A AS A
            ON A.Column1 = B.Column1
WHERE   A.Column1 IS NULL;
```

In this by left joining to `table_A` then stating that `A.Column1` has to be `NULL`, you are removing any records that already exist in `Table_A`.

I prefer the former (`NOT EXISTS`), because I think the intent is much more clear, but if you [use MySQL the latter will perform better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246793/1048425)

Or you could also use:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A(column1)
SELECT  Column1
FROM    Table_B AS B
WHERE   B.Column1 IS NOT NULL
AND     B.COlumn1 NOT IN (SELECT A.Column1 FROM Table_A AS A WHERE A.Column1 IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a MERGE statement?

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_A a
USING TABLE_B b ON (a.column1=b.column1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (column1) VALUES (b.column1);
```