# T-SQL stored procedure with joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with a stored procedure. I have 3 tables for a mass mailing service and I want to know how many tasks (table - `MMProcessItem`) I still need to do...

I have these 3 tables:

[image: Tables]

Here is my select:

```
SELECT
    MMAddress.AddressID, MMProcess.ProcessID
FROM 
    MMProcess, MMAddress
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM MMProcessItem) Items ON Items.AddressID = MMAddress.AddressID
WHERE 
    Items.ResultID IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    ProcessID, AddressID
```

And my SQL Code is working fine if there is nothing in MMProcessItem table, this is what I get:

[image]

But if I send 1 email, like the one with AddressID = 1 and ProcessID = 1, I don't get anymore the 1 record with AddressID = 1 and ProcessID = 2, I should get a total of 3 records, but what i get is a total of 2 records...

[image]

Sorry if this is an amateur mistake, im not used to work with t-sql and do these type of things...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should ***most definitely NOT*** mix the two styles!!

Comment: Worse is mixing them.  Usually works but not technically supported by anybody AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your join to `MMProcessItem` requires two predicates, one to join to `MMProcess`, and one to join to `MMAddress`. You are currently only joining to `MMAddress`. That means that when you add a record with `AddressID` = 1 and `ProcessID` = 1 it removes both records where `AddressID` = 1, not just the one record where `AddressID` is 1 **and** `ProcessID` is 1.

You could rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT  a.AddressID, p.ProcessID
FROM    MMProcess AS p
        CROSS JOIN MMAddress AS a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MMProcessItem AS i 
            ON i.AddressID = a.AddressID
            AND i.ProcessID = p.ProcessID
WHERE   i.ResultID IS NULL
ORDER BY p.ProcessID, a.AddressID;
```

*Note the use of explicit join syntax, and also aliases for brevity*

Since you are using the `LEFT JOIN` to `MMProcessItem` solely for the reason of removing records, then you might find that using `NOT EXISTS` conveys intention better, but more importantly, [it can also perform better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246793/1048425).

```
SELECT  a.AddressID, p.ProcessID
FROM    MMProcess AS p
        CROSS JOIN MMAddress AS a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT   1
            FROM    MMProcessItem AS i 
            WHERE   i.AddressID = a.AddressID
            AND     i.ProcessID = p.ProcessID
        )
ORDER BY p.ProcessID, a.AddressID;
```

Comment: Thank you ! You saved me ! :)