# SQL Query Total Records

Tags: sql

I'm really struggling with this query. I have 2 tables, one for "users" and one for "orders". "users" has a field "user_id" and "orders" also has a field "user_id".

I need to know total records of Users with 0 records in the "orders" table. In other words, if I have 1000 users registered in the "users" table, how many of those never placed an order on the site.

I tried to come with something like this but of course it's incorrect:

```
SELECT Count(u.user_id) as tRecs, o.orderid
FROM users u
    INNER JOIN orders o ON u.user_id = o.user_id
```

Comment: Something like `select count(*) from users u where not exists(select 'x' from orders o where o.user_id = u.user_id)` perhaps?

Comment: Looking good. Let me play with that. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe go w/ Tanjim's answer - one of them is bound to be more performant.  Maybe he'll explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `Left Join`

```
SELECT COUNT(A.UserID) FROM Users A LEFT JOIN Orders B ON A.UserID = B.UserID WHERE B.UserID IS NULL
```

or `Not Exists`

```
SELECT COUNT(A.USERID) FROM Users A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT UserID FROM Orders X WHERE X.UserID = A.UserID)
```

or `Not In`

```
SELECT COUNT(A.USERID) FROM Users A WHERE A.UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM Orders)
```

Depending on your DBMS for performance you wanna see this [What's the difference between NOT EXISTS vs. NOT IN vs. LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null)

Comment: 2nd one you have the alias wrong (should be where X.UserID = A.UserID).  And won't let last one have issues on many DBMS when number of records in Orders goes above a certain number?

Comment: @Tibrogargan, did you mean `Not IN` issues?

Comment: Yeah.  A few months ago a project I was working on got tripped up by trying to put more than *X* values in a `NOT IN` clause.  May have not have stemmed from the DBMS though

Comment: How on earth we people face same types of problem together !!! I also faced that later then I always rely on `join` or `exists`.