# SQL, PHP, sorting content of table by content of other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a bit of a problem with some sql. I am have to tables in the same mysql database, called total and dismissed. In both of there is a column called person_id.
I am trying to get the every record from total, minus the ones in dismissed.

So if the table total has the values: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

and dismissed has: `3,4,7`

I want only `1,2,5,6` to be displayed from the table.

My sql looks like this at the moment:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM total WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dismissed WHERE total.person_id = dismissed.person_id)";
```

And the rest of the code is:

```
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";


$conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Fail:' . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM total WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dismissed WHERE total.person_id =  dismissed.person_id)";

//$sql = "SELECT * FROM total";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);          //First error message

while($feed_varer=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {                 //Second error message

//some code

}
```

I have not problem connecting to the database using when doing something like `$sql = "SELECT * FROM total";` , and the rest of the code works in that case too.

The error message i gets is:
Warning: `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in url-to-page.php` 
(url shortened). The error message is given twice, the lines are marked in the code.
Hope you can help me.

tried to test query like this: (Thanks Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan)

```
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM total ORDER BY person_id")) {
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    printf($row_cnt);
    $result->close();
}
```

Result showed the correct amount of rows.

Comment: Have you tried searching your error message?

Answer (score 3):

This happens usually when the mysqli_query hasnt run properly. Check whether $query is executed properly or does it contains anything or not. The problem may be with the connection or it may be with the query or it may be with the tables. Be sure $query contains the results.

Try this

```
if (!$result) {
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($result);
        exit;
    }
```

Let us know what is the mysql error

Comment: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first problem I see is the second part of your SQL command 
`SELECT 1 FROM dismissed WHERE total.person_id =  dismissed.person_id` 
Why are you selecting 1? 

Secondly I would use `NOT IN` rather than `NOT EXIST` as this is more efficient [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null)
Thirdly the `WHERE` function should include a column

Comment: tried `$sql = "SELECT * FROM total WHERE person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM dismissed)";` but gave the same error