# Deleting all the rows which doesn't have any link with depended table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One is `students` and another is `studentPerformance`

`students` table contains
`id`, `name` and `email_id`

`studentPerformance` table contains `id`, `student_id`, `marks`

My question is, how I can delete all the students from `students` table who doesn't have any record in `studentPerformance` table?

I did Google but didn't land any proper place.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: **`not exists`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join:

```
 DELETE s 
 FROM Students AS s 
 LEFT JOIN StudentPerformance AS sp
  ON sp.student_id = s.id 
 WHERE sp.student_id IS NULL; -- where not match was found (no sp-row)
```

or not exists:

```
 DELETE s 
 FROM Students AS s 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM StudentPerformance AS sp WHERE sp.student_id = s.id);
```

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, which method is faster?

Comment: The main difference is in the returned columns (in a select). In general, if you don't need the data, go for not exists, which is also usually somewhat faster, but this is a delete so again, not exists is probably best.

Comment: @abbas NOT EXISTS is faster

Comment: @AceAmr Do you have *any* evidence for such an assertion?

Comment: If you set up a SELECT test, the query plan should be different (I think it's filter a step that differs).

Comment: @MatBailie This is been discussed many times before. See -https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: Also discussed on SO here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`, `not in`, or `left join`/`where`:

```
delete s from students s
   where not exists (select 1 from studentperformance sp where sp.student_id = s.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

--run this script and watch the result

create table #students
(
    id int,
    name varchar(20),
    email_id varchar(30)
)

insert into #students
(
    id,
    name,
    email_id
)
values
(
    1,
    'jan',
    'jan@gmail.com'
),
(
    2,
    'Peter',
    'peter@gmail.com'
),
(
    7,
    'Pierre',
    'pierre@gmail.com'
),
(
    12,
    'Peter',
    'peter@gmail.com'
)

create table #studentPerformance
(
    id int,
    student_id int,
    marks int
)

insert into #studentPerformance
(
    id,
    student_id,
    marks
)
values
(
    1,
    2,
    6
),
(
    1,
    7,
    8
)

delete #students from #students
where id not in (select student_id from #studentPerformance)

--student 1 and 12 don't have performed so they where deleted

--student 2 and 7 won't be deleted

select *
from #students

drop table #students

drop table #studentPerformance