# SQL to SQLAlchemy translation

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a, somewhat odd, query that gets me all the items in a parent table that have no matches in its corresponding child table.

If possible, id like to turn it into an SQLAlchemy query.  But I have no idea how.  I can do basic gets and filters, but this one is beyond my experience so far.  Any help you folks might give would be greatly appreciated.

```
class customerTranslations(Base):
    """parent table. holds customer names"""
    __tablename__ = 'customer_translation'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class customerEmails(Base):
    """child table. hold emails for customers in translation table"""
    __tablename__ = 'customer_emails'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customer_translation.id'))
```

I want to build:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_translation 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM customer_emails)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *subquery*, so create one first:

```
all_emails_stmnt = session.query(customerEmails.parent_id).subquery()
```

and then you can use that to filter your other table:

```
translations_with_no_email = session.query(customerTranslations).filter(
    ~customerTranslations.id.in_(all_emails_stmnt))
```

This produces the same SQL (but with all the column names expanded, rather than using `*`, the ORM then can create your objects):

```
>>> all_emails_stmnt = session.query(customerEmails.parent_id).subquery()
>>> print(all_emails_stmnt)
SELECT customer_emails.parent_id
FROM customer_emails
>>> translations_with_no_email = session.query(customerTranslations).filter(
...     ~customerTranslations.id.in_(all_emails_stmnt))
>>> print(translations_with_no_email)
SELECT customer_translation.id AS customer_translation_id
FROM customer_translation
WHERE customer_translation.id NOT IN (SELECT customer_emails.parent_id
FROM customer_emails)
```

You could also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists

has_no_email_stmnt = ~exists().where(customerTranslations.id == customerEmails.parent_id)
translations_with_no_email = session.query(customerTranslations).filter(has_no_email_stmnt)
```

or, if you have a a backreference on the `customerTranslations` class pointing to emails, named `emails`, use `.any()` on the relationship and invert:

```
 session.query(customerTranslations).filter(
    ~customerTranslations.emails.any())
```

Back in 2010 [`NOT EXISTS` was a little slower on MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null) but you may want to re-assess if that is still the case.

Comment: Is there any way to write it using this format?
`customerTranslations.query.filter(etc etc)`

Comment: Yes, just move from `session.query(Class).filter(...)` to `Class.query.filter(...)`

Comment: Amazing.  Thanks again.  One more expansion if I could.  How would I would I go about finding matches with a specific number of hits?  For example - psuedocode: `SELECT * FROM customerTranslations WHERE (there are 3 matches in the customerEmails table)`

Comment: @user3723688: for the subquery, use `db.session.query(customerEmails.parent_id).subquery()` (where `db` is the `SQLAlchemy()` class from the Flask-SQLAlchemy library).

Comment: @user3723688: To get a minimum number of email rows you'd have to use `EXISTS (...)` or `WHERE id IN (...)` on a subselect with grouping on `parent_id` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 2`.

Comment: @user3723688: you really should look over the [ORM tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html), which teaches how to create such queries.

Comment: `three_or_more_emails = session.query(customerEmails).filter(customerEmails.parent_id == customerTranslations.id).group_by(customerEmails.id).having(func.count(customerEmails.id) >= 3).exists()` and `session.query(customerTranslations).filter(three_or_more_emails)` produces `SELECT customer_translation.id AS customer_translation_id FROM customer_translation WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customer_emails WHERE customer_emails.parent_id = customer_translation.id GROUP BY customer_emails.id HAVING count(customer_emails.id) >= 3)`.